# Prevent `ng-include` from creating isolated scope. AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive, angularjs-ng-include

I am using `ng-include src` directive at multiple places in my HTML. Each `ng-include` is creating an isolated scope for itself which apparently is causing a lot of trouble for me.

For example.

```
<div ng-controller="parent">
    <div ng-include src="'id1'">
    </div>
    <div ng-include src="'id2'">
    </div>
    <div ng-include src="'id2'">
    </div>
</div>
```

In the html mentioned above, 4 scopes are getting created. 1 at parent where `controller` is defined and 3 are getting created by default at each `ng-include src`.

Is it at all possible to prevent `ng-include` from creating an isolated scope for itself? If It is not possible then is there a workaround for it?

Comment: simply create your own directive and load template through it, without declaring isolated scope

Comment: @pankajparkar How? Do you have any example as to how it can be done?

Comment: ng-include doesn't create an isolated scope - it creates a child scope that is not isolated from the parent.  Before you reinvent the wheel with a new directive, I'd be interested to understand what kind of trouble is being caused.  A child scope is created for a reason - it prevents the templates from interfering with each other.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger `ng-model` used in those templated, loaded by 'ng-include src' are not updated in parent controller.

Comment: This is the classic "dot notation" problem in Angular.  [The first and second answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model) should shed some light on a better way to address your issue.  It can also be solved by using the "ControllerAs" syntax.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger I am aware of it. To implement this I'll have to change a whole lot of code which I am planning to do later on. Was looking for a quick solution for now.

Comment: This answer creates a directive similar to ng-repeat without an isolate scope: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17340138/1221537

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to create a your own directive that can load specified template withoud isolated scope.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="parent">
    <div my-directive template-path="id1">
    </div>
    <div my-directive template-path="id2">
    </div>
    <div my-directive template-path="id2">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      templateUrl: function(ele, attrs) {
          return attrs.templatePath;
      }
  };
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/nX2B7gXmH12MpJh9vgfc?p=preview)

Comment: Its not returning anything.

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe see my updated answer, added `restrict: 'AE'` attribute support to directive

Comment: It worked! thanks a lot man. I ended up giving hard coded path at templateurl in the directive, but It solved the issue of scope. +1 for the solution.

Comment: no you shouldn't hardcode it, then it would not be used as reusable component

Comment: Well yeah, but there is some error when I am using `function(ele, attrs) {
          return attrs.templatePath;
      }` Currently fixing it.

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe check my added plunkr'

Comment: Did something change about Angular? This doesn't work for me at all. Seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Good solution. Keep in mind this will work only if 1) the attr doesn't need to be interpolated and 2) templatePath never changes.