# Invalid data bind in the multi controller page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here my code:

index.html:

```
<head>
   <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'route.html',
                controller: 'RouteController',
            }).otherwise('/');
}]);

app.controller('RouteController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.hello='world';
}]);

app.controller('IncController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.field = '';
    $scope.test = function() {
        console.log('test=' + $scope.field);
    }
}]);
```

route.html:

```
<div>
hello world
<div>{{hello}}</div>
<ng-include src="'including.html'"
            ng-controller="IncController"></ng-include>
</div>
```

including.html:

```
<input type='text' ng-model='field'/>
<input type='button' ng-click='test()'/>
```

When I click button test() function is calling, but field is always empty. 
If I make route for including.html it works when I go to this route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you have used `ng-include` while rendering `including.html`. As when you used `ng-include` it creates a child scope which is prototypically inherited from the parent scope.

You need to follow the `dot rule` while defining `ng-model` in such cases, which will tend to use [**`Prototypal Javascript Inheritance`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) & will take value from the object.

You need to define one object called `model` which will have various property in it, like `$scope.model = { 'field': '' }`

**Markup**

```
<input type='text' ng-model='model.field'/>
<input type='button' ng-click='test()'/>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('IncController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = { 'field': '' };
    $scope.test = function() {
        console.log('test=' + $scope.model.field);
    }
}]);
```

**Edit**

You could also write your own directive like `ng-include` which load a template from `URL` but it will not create a child scope.

You could refer this approach [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29115532/2435473)

Comment: Is there exists other method to do that?

Comment: @nuclearkote look at the edit..I added the edit part

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of the error, but I have found another method to fix it. I replaced ng-include with a simple directive and now it works well.

app.directive('test', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       templateUrl: 'including.html',
}
});