# Angularjs table sort with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, html-table

I have an HTML table and want to sort my records (`$scope.records` in ctrl) by clicking on table headers (`$scope.headers` in ctrl),

Can anyone explain why does that work:

```
<th>
    <a ng-click="sortColumn=headers[0];reverse=!reverse">{{ headers[0] }}</a>
</th>
<th>
    <a ng-click="sortColumn=headers[1];reverse=!reverse">{{ headers[1] }}</a>
</th>
```

And that doesn't:

```
<th ng-repeat="header in headers">
    <a ng-click="sortColumn=headers[$index];reverse=!reverse">{{ headers[$index] }}</a>
</th>
```

Here is the code for the records:

```
<tr ng-repeat="arr in records | orderBy:sortColumn:reverse">
    <td ng-repeat="val in arr" ng-bind-html-unsafe="arr[headers[$index]]</td>
</tr>
```

I have 58 columns in my table so would be much better to loop through the table headers...

Comment: What, exactly, does not work about the second solution?

Off-hand, I'm going to guess that in your <td ng-repeat> $index is being bound to the td repeat, not the tr repeat, but I don't quite have enough information to say for certain. Have you tried looking at the scope using batarang?

Comment: PLease see Gloopy-s reply, I think I learned something new about primitives in the repeat scope ;) thx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As David suggested this is likely scope related. Since [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat) creates a new scope your `ngClick` is setting the `sortColumn` and `reverse` in its own child scope for each column header.

One way around this to ensure you are modifying the values in the same scope would be to create a function on the scope and call that in your ngClick passing in the index:

```
$scope.toggleSort = function(index) {
    if($scope.sortColumn === $scope.headers[index]){
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    }                    
    $scope.sortColumn = $scope.headers[index];
}
```

with this as your markup:

```
<th ng-repeat="header in headers">
    <a ng-click="toggleSort($index)">{{ headers[$index] }}</a>
</th>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dsqH/) with an example.

---

Another option would be to bind to a non-primitive type like this (the child scopes will be accessing the same object):

```
$scope.columnSort = { sortColumn: 'col1', reverse: false };
```

with this as your markup:

```
<th ng-repeat="header in headers">
    <a ng-click="columnSort.sortColumn=headers[$index];columnSort.reverse=!columnSort.reverse">{{ headers[$index] }}</a>
</th>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/1/) with an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working! Really appreciate your help, I found the second solution to be ... hmmm ... just nicer as I don't need to create a new sort function in my controller. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 3):

Extending Gloopy's answer, yet another option is to modify the parent's properties in the ng-repeat for the primitive types:

```
<a ng-click="$parent.sortColumn=headers[$index];$parent.reverse=!$parent.reverse">{{ headers[$index] }}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/q3Nfu/).

Note however that $parent is not a documented property of [scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope), so this is somewhat of a hack, so use at your own risk.

I wish AngularJS had a better way of dealing with these "inner scopes" that are created by ng-repeat, ng-switch, etc. because quite often we need to modify parent scope properties that are primitives.

See also Gloopy's insightful comment about scope inheritance as it relates to primitives and non-primitives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12415198/215945).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what sort of data is in your records, so for my sample I just used an array of JSON values. I have tried several different sorting plugins for my Javascript with Angular and nothing worked. In the long run I have discovered you don't necessarily need those extras.

Since AngularJS is good at processing javascript data-structures for displaying in HTML, you can just rearrange the javascript-arrays in memory, and AngularJS picks up on the changes. **This example allows clicking the headers of the table, which will trigger a sorting based on that columns data type. If it is already sorted on that column, it will reverse-sort the column.** The type detection is done through the presented isNumeric() function, and one two-tiny tweaks:

1. Added checks if inputting on the '#' symbol as a header and sorts as a number in the toggleSort method. This can easily be removed by users if preferred.
2. When toggleSort attempts to sort alphabetically, if it catches a TypeError it then switches to sorting on numbers.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {

  $scope.samplePositions = [
   {"#": "1", "Unique ID": "100130", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 1", "Status": "Available"},
   {"#": "2", "Unique ID": "100131", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 2", "Status": "Available"},
   {"#": "3", "Unique ID": "100132", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 3", "Status": "Available"},
   {"#": "4", "Unique ID": "100133", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 4", "Status": "Available"},
   {"#": "5", "Unique ID": "100134", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 5", "Status": "Checked Out"},
   {"#": "6", "Unique ID": "100135", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 6", "Status": "Checked Out"},
   {"#": "7", "Unique ID": "100136", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 7", "Status": "Checked Out"},
   {"#": "8", "Unique ID": "100137", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 8", "Status": "Checked Out"},
   {"#": "9", "Unique ID": "100138", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 1 - Box 1 - Position 1", "Status": "Available"},
   {"#": "10", "Unique ID": "100139", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 2 - Box 1 - Position 1", "Status": "Available"},
   {"#": "11", "Unique ID": "100140", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 2 - Box 1 - Position 2", "Status": "Available"},
   {"#": "12", "Unique ID": "100141", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 2 - Box 1 - Position 3", "Status": "Lost"},
   {"#": "13", "Unique ID": "100142", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 2 - Box 1 - Position 4", "Status": "Lost"},
   {"#": "14", "Unique ID": "100143", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 3 - Box 1 - Position 1", "Status": "Available"},
   {"#": "15", "Unique ID": "100144", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 3 - Box 1 - Position 2", "Status": "Available"},
   {"#": "16", "Unique ID": "100145", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 4 - Box 1 - Position 1", "Status": "Checked Out"},
   {"#": "17", "Unique ID": "100146", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 4 - Box 1 - Position 2", "Status": "Available"},
   {"#": "18", "Unique ID": "100147", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 4 - Box 1 - Position 3", "Status": "Available"},
   {"#": "19", "Unique ID": "100148", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 4 - Box 1 - Position 4", "Status": "Checked Out"},
   {"#": "20", "Unique ID": "100149", "Name": "Book", "Section": "Paraguay", "Position": "Shelf 1 - Rack 5 - Box 1 - Position 1", "Status": "Available"}  
  ]
  
  // Dynamically get the entry headers to use with displaying the nested data via header-key lookups
  // Assumes all lines contain same key-text data
 $scope.samplePositionsHeaderKeys = []; // Contains only the key-data, not the values
 for (var key in $scope.samplePositions[0]) {
  if ($scope.samplePositions[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   $scope.samplePositionsHeaderKeys.push(key);
  }
 }
  
  /**
   * Determine if the input value is a number or not.
    * @param n The input value to be checked for numeric status.
   * @returns true if parameter is numeric, or false otherwise.
   * 
   * This method uses the following evaluations to determine if input is a numeric:
   * 
   *   (5); // true  
   *   ('123'); // true  
   *   ('123abc'); // false  
   *   ('q345'); // false
   *   (null); // false
   *   (""); // false
   *  ([]); // false
   *   ('   '); // false
   *   (true); // false
   *   (false); // false
   *   (undefined); // false
   *   (new String('')); // false
   * 
   * @author C.D. (modified by)
   * @original https://stackoverflow.com/a/1421988/10930451
   * 
   */
  function isNumeric(n) {
   if (!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && !isNaN(n - 0) && n !== null && n !== "") {
    return true;
   }
   return false;
  }

  /**
   * Column Sort Method (generic). Sort based on target column header or reverse sort if already selected on that.
   * @param dataSource The array of JSON data to be sorted
   * @param headers The array of JSON object-keys (table column headers) to be referenced
   * @param index The target JSON object-key to sort the table columns based upon
   * 
   * @author C.D.
   */
  $scope.lastSortIndex = 0;
  $scope.toggleSort = function (dataSource, headers, index) {
   if ($scope.lastSortIndex === index) {
    dataSource.reverse();
   }
   else {
    var key = headers[index];
    if (key === "#" || isNumeric(dataSource[key])) { // Compare as numeric or on '#' sign
     dataSource.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a[key]) - parseFloat(b[key]));
    }
    else // Compare as Strings
    {
     try { // Attempt to sort as Strings
      dataSource.sort((a, b) => a[key].localeCompare(b[key]));
     } catch (error) {
      if (error.name === 'TypeError') { // Catch type error, actually sort as Numeric
       dataSource.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a[key]) - parseFloat(b[key]));
      }
     }
    }
    $scope.lastSortIndex = index;
   }
  }

});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>AngularJS - Hello World</title>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.1.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.13" data-semver="1.3.13" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="header in samplePositionsHeaderKeys">
       <a ng-click="toggleSort(samplePositions, samplePositionsHeaderKeys, $index)">{{ header }}</a>
      </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
  
    <tbody>
     <!-- Data is nested, so double-repeat to extract and display -->
     <tr ng-repeat="row in samplePositions" >
      <td ng-repeat="key in samplePositionsHeaderKeys">
       {{row[key]}}
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have put together a working [Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/2nugXqsI2uXdltH6as4C?p=preview) to demonstrate. Just click on the headers and they will sort the array in memory, where AngularJS will pick up on the changes and refresh that portion of the DOM.