# AngularJS: input not binding to expected scope when inside a view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue with binding an input from inside a view. I thought it would bind to the controller scope, but it seems to be binding to a child scope, so it's not updating above.

Other items will bind like I expect if they're inside an ng-repeat (I'm not sure why).

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hMpsB/1/

What's the best way to bind the input to the correct scope if it's not inside an ng-repeat?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your example you will have better luck binding your `$scope.test` to an object instead of a primitive type like this:

```
$scope.test = { val: "test value" };
```

You can see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cvQ5/) for a working example.

The child scope that gets created in the [ngView](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngView) will copy your value and since your original `$scope.test` is a primitive string it has no link to the parent value so your input will be modifying the child scope copy. When binding to an object your child scope has a copy of the object reference but will ultimately modify the same instance of the object.

You can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574765/better-design-for-passing-data-to-other-ng-views-in-angularjs-persisting-it-ac) for more information on creating a service to persist data across multiple controllers (which is a little similar to your question).

You can also look into using `$parent` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12749969/1207991) though as Mark mentions it's undocumented and might get messy if another child scope ever gets introduced somewhere.