# Where to put user defined functions in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, scope, angularjs

In my view, I want to render:

```
<p>
  {{ say() }}
</p>
```

Where `say` is defined as such:

```
say = function() {
  return "Hello World";
}
```

I can define it in my controller:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.say = function() { ... };
}
```

But then it's only accessible within that controller.

If I define the function outside the Angular file structure, it renders nothing. Same if I define it in my `controllers.js` file, but outside a controller function scope.

Where is the proper place to put my function, so I can render it in any controller?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

One way is to [create a service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) with the functions you want to share across multiple controllers. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12008908/1207991) for more info.

After you do so you can inject the service you created into any controller and access the `say()` function with code something like this:

```
function TestCtrl($scope, myService){
   $scope.say = myService.say;
}
```

Where you defined `myService` as:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .factory('myService', function () {
        return {
            say: function () {
                return "Hello World";
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3tGd/) with an example.

Comment: Awesome... I was expecting it to be in with the services, but couldn't find the syntax to add it in

Comment: Just FYI, an alternate syntax (I prefer seeing/reading 'service' instead of 'factory' if I only need a constructor function):
.service('myService', function () {
  this.say = function () { return "Hello World"; }
});

Comment: The "problem" with a proper service is that each time you use the service, you get a new instance of that service. In this case it might not be the best idea.

Comment: @Spock Yes, so maybe angular should add something like 'singleton bean'.