# Angularjs - dynamic pages, same template, how to access and load article by id

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am slightly puzzled on how to use angularjs to build a blog-like web site.

If you think of an ordinary blog,,, and say,, I am building it using php and mysql.. what I don't understand is how do I make angular get an article based on id..

I can load data for a list of all articles.. I can load data for a single page (from a static json),, I understand how to send http requests,, but how do I access

```
mysite.com/page?id=1 or 
mysite.com/page?id=2 or 
mysite.com/page?id=3
```

Obviously, I want to load the same template for each separate blog post.. but I have not yet seen a single example that explains this simply.

If I have three posts in my database with id 1,2,3 how is angular meant to generate links to each individual article? I understand that I can load data to assemble urls but what urls? I suppose I am confused with routing.

Could you recommend a SIMPLE and understandable example of this? Could you suggest how to think about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this short explanation I will use examples based on [official tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/).
Propably somwhere in your application you created controllers module with code close to that:

```
var blogControllers = angular.module('blogControllers', []);

// other controllers etc.

blogControllers.controller('BlogPostCtrl', ['$scope',
// more and more of controller code
```

We will be back here in a moment :) If you have controllers module, you can create a route linked to the specific controller:

```
var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'blogControllers'
]);

blogApp .config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      // other routes
      when('/post/:postId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/blog-post.html',
        controller: 'BlogPostCtrl'
      }).
      // other...
  }]);
```

Well but what we can do with this `:postId` parameter? Lets go back to our controller:

```
blogControllers.controller('BlogPostCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'BlogPost',
  function($scope, $routeParams, BlogPost) {
    $scope.post = BlogPost.get({postId: $routeParams.postId});
  }]);
```

As you see, we are passing `$routeParams` here and then our `BlogPost` resource (it will be explained). Simplifying (again), in `$routeParams` you have all the params that you put in the `$routeProvider` for exact route (so `:postId` in our example). We got the id, now the magic happens ;)

First you need to add [services and/or factories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory) to your app (and look, we are using [ngResource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource)):

```
var blogServices = angular.module('blogServices ', ['ngResource']);

blogServices.factory('BlogPost', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('action/to/get/:postId.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params: { postId: 'all' }, isArray:true}
    });
  }]);
```

Now you know what is our `BlogPost` in controller :) As you see default value for `postId` is "all" and yes, our api should retrieve all posts for postId = "all". Of course you can do this in your own way and separate this to two factories, one for details and one for list/index.

How to print all of the blog names? Quite simple. Add list routing without any special params. You already know how to do this so let's skip it and continue with our list controller:

```
blogControllers.controller('BlogListCtrl', ['$scope', 'BlogPost',
  function($scope, BlogPost) {
    $scope.blogPosts = BlogPost.query(); // no params, so we are taking all posts
  }]);
```

Voila! All posts in our `$scope` variable! Thanks to this, they are accessible in the template/view :) Now we just need to iterate those posts in our view, for example:

```
<ul class="blog-posts">
    <li ng-repeat="blogPost in blogPosts">
        <a href="#/post/{{blogPost.id}}">{{blogPost.title}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is it:) I hope you will find AngularJS quite easy now!
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much! I still struggle a little but it is becoming easier as I go. I need to master authentication and a few other things and it will get better.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to use for this is $routeParams. Have a look at this video from egghead.io which explains how to use it:

http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-routeparams

Comment: This video explains how to pass parameters to a controller. You'll then need to use that parameter to do an AJAX call to get the blog data or HTML for the post contents.

Comment: OK, I see how I can use this to build my links and pass parameters. I will play with this. When you say AJAX you refer to angularjs $http? I would love to see it in action but this video does help quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to use hash navigation. So your routing should look like this

```
mysite.com/blog/#!/id=1
mysite.com/blog/#!/id=2
```