# sharing a var between views/controllers

Tags: angularjs

I know this question has been asked 100s of times but i have yet to succeed in implementing this after reading countless of threads... shame on me.

I know this is a lot of code (sorry). But I just can't find what I'm doing wrong, 
So to the problem I want to add something to the list in pat1 then click over to pat2 and see the same list.

Routing;

```
var routeApp = angular.module('routeApp', ['ngRoute', 'rootMod']);

routeApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/pat1', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/pat1.html',
        controller: 'pageOneCont'
    }).
    when('/pat2', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/pat2.html',
        controller: 'pageTwoCont'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/pat1'
    });
}]);
```

Controllers & Service:

```
    var rootMod = angular.module('rootMod', []);


rootMod.controller('pageOneCont', [ 'serv', '$scope', function (serv, $scope) {
    'use strict';

    // Your controller implementation goes here ...
    $scope.handleClick = function ($scope, serv){
        var updateFoo = function(){
            $scope.foo = serv.foo;
        };

        aService.registerObserverCallback(updateFoo);
        //service now in control of updating foo
    };
}]);

rootMod.controller('pageTwoCont', [ 'serv', '$scope', function (serv, $scope) {
    'use strict';

    // Your controller implementation goes here ...
    $scope.handleClick = function ($scope, serv){
        var updateFoo = function(){
            $scope.foo = serv.foo;
        };

        aService.registerObserverCallback(updateFoo);
        //service now in control of updating foo
    };
}]);

/* Service */
rootMod.factory('serv', [ function () {

    var observerCallbacks = [];

    //register an observer
    this.registerObserverCallback = function(callback){
        observerCallbacks.push(callback);
    };

    //call this when you know 'foo' has been changed
    var notifyObservers = function(){
        angular.forEach(observerCallbacks, function(callback){
            callback();
        });
    };
}]);
```

INDEX.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="routeApp">
<head>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <li><a href="#pat1"> ONE </a></li>
    <li><a href="#pat2"> TWO </a></li>
</body>
<!-- SinglePage -->
<div ng-view></div>
</html>
```

PAT1.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>

<div ><!--ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="ContactController">-->
  <h1> ONE </h1>
  <button ng-click="handleClick"> BROADCAST </button>
  <div ng-repeat="item in foo">{{ item }}</div> 
</div>
</html>
```

PAT2.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>

<div> <!--ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="ContactController">-->
  <h1> TWO </h1>
  <div ng-repeat="item in foo">{{ item }}</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### JS

1. Your service is injected as `serv` in your controllers but you call `aService`. Use `serv` instead.
2. You should use `rootMod.service()` instead of `rootMod.factory()` since you are using `this` and not returning anything in your service function (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15914263/1796523) for the difference between factories and services).
3. There is no `serv.foo` property. You have to add `this.foo = /** something **/;` to your service function.

So this should work:

```
var rootMod = angular.module('rootMod', []);


rootMod.controller('pageOneCont', [ 'serv', '$scope', function (serv, $scope) {
    'use strict';

    // Your controller implementation goes here ...
    $scope.handleClick = function ($scope, serv){
        var updateFoo = function(){
            $scope.foo = serv.foo;
        };

        serv.registerObserverCallback(updateFoo);
        // service now in control of updating foo
    };
}]);

rootMod.controller('pageTwoCont', [ 'serv', '$scope', function (serv, $scope) {
    'use strict';

    // Your controller implementation goes here ...
    $scope.handleClick = function ($scope, serv){
        var updateFoo = function(){
            $scope.foo = serv.foo;
        };

        serv.registerObserverCallback(updateFoo);
        // service now in control of updating foo
    };
}]);

/* Service */

rootMod.service('serv', [ function () {

    var observerCallbacks = [];

    // call this when you know 'foo' has been changed
    var notifyObservers = function(){
        angular.forEach(observerCallbacks, function(callback){
            callback();
        });
    };

    // initialize foo here
    this.foo = '';

    // register an observer
    this.registerObserverCallback = function(callback){
        observerCallbacks.push(callback);
    };
}]);
```

### HTML

You put the `ng-view` container outside of the `body`. It has to be inside. Also the path to a view starts with `#/` so you have to change your links.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="routeApp">
    <head>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <li><a href="#/pat1"> ONE </a></li>
        <li><a href="#/pat2"> TWO </a></li>
        <!-- SinglePage -->
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Each view only needs the content that should be placed inside the `ng-view` container. So you mustn't make a complete HTML document.

**pat1.html**

```
<h1> ONE </h1>
<button ng-click="handleClick"> BROADCAST </button>
<div ng-repeat="item in foo">{{ item }}</div>
```

**pat2.html**

```
<h1> TWO </h1>
<div ng-repeat="item in foo">{{ item }}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! But i still dont get how i ge the context of the "serv" foo on both pages. With these changes it just resets the foo array when i switch page. Because im just calling {{ foo }}in the html...

Comment: See my update. Maybe you could do a small [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this? And what do you intend to do in your application in the first place?

Comment: Just trying to understand how it woorks, not planning to do annything "real" just yet :P ,  thanks for the help... but even with these cahnges i get nothing in my service. i know i dont add annything to it annyhwere. But i can't understand how i add stuff to this shared list...

Comment: Look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/xwP3w/). There are two controllers that share a service similar to yours. If you click the button of `Ctrl1` an element is appended to the list of the service. `Ctrl2` binds the reference of the list array to its scope and builds a `ul` out of it. Since the array is shared by reference both controllers work with the same object and the `ul` us updated immediately.

Comment: The porblem was me resetting the variable i when switching view. So it made duplicates when i was set to 0 when switching from view 1 to view two via routing. I moved the variable to the Service and made get / set function and used that for the counter. Ty for your help :)