# Why service() method has no official documentation?

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

I'm getting started in AngularJS and I see people is talking about a "service() vs factory()" dilema but I cannot find any documentation about the first one.

So, should we force ourself to use factory()? or it's just like an alias?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sentences I wish I had read when I started using angular.

- A provider is a function that gets `new`ed. And can be injected into a config block in that state.

  When its time to be used (ie. injected elsewhere) `$get` is called and the return value from that is your provider.
- A service is a function that gets `new`ed  and thats your service.
- A factory is a function that gets `new`ed and executed. Its return value is your factory.

The three different terms are just to differentiate the method in which they're created.

Some good uses for each:

- provider: 
  As a configuration for an angular library or api service
- service: a 'class like' object. Maybe for storing shared application data
- factory: a data retrieval object that handles getting and saving of data.. maybe into your service.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a class or function constructor to the service. Angular will do the equivalent of calling "new" on it.

Pass a function that returns the object you want to the factory. Angular will take what you pass, call it, and use the return value.

For example, factory:

```
function(dep1, dep2) {
   return {
       total: dep1.x + dep2.x 
   };
}
```

Service:

```
function MyClass(dep1, dep2) {
   this.total = dep1.x + dep2.x 
}
```

Factory is usually fine unless you are using a language like TypeScript or CoffeeScript that directs you more to classes.

The Provider is simply a service that can be configured once. In other words, if you have something that needs to be set up when you are initializing modules in the config block, use a provider. That allows you to tweak configuration before it is stored as an object to be used.

Let me know if that answers your question!