# update a service variable within an $http callback

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm using a service to make user data available to various controllers in my Angular app.  I'm stuck trying to figure out how to use the $http service to update a variable local to the service (in my case "this.users").  I've tried with and without promises.  The server is responding correctly.

I've read several excellent articles for how to use $http within a service to update the scope of a controller.  The best being this one: http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.com/2013/03/MovingAjaxCallsToACustomServiceInAngularJS.html.  That does not help me though because it negates the benefits of using a service.  Mainly, modifying the scope in one controller does not modify throughout the rest of the app.

Here is what I have thus far.

```
app.service('UserService', ['$http', function($http) {
    this.users = [];

    this.load = function() {
        var promise = $http.get('users.json')
            .success(function(data){
                // this.users is undefined here
                console.log(this.users);
            }
    };

    promise.then(function() {
        // this.users is undefined here
        console.log('this.users');
    });
}]);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
var users = [];
```

rather than

```
this.users = [];
```

and see what

```
console.log(users);
```

outputs in each of those cases.

Comment: You are correct.  However, how then would I bind a controller $scope variable to users?

Comment: you wouldn't, in your controller, you would have to make an explicit call to get that from the user service

Comment: What about 2-way binding.  Lets say I have $scope.users in my controller that I update with a getter method from the service.  I want to be able to update the service users value when $scope.users changes.  I realize I could implement a setter method on the service but then I have to handle binding manually everywhere.  That seems to reduce the value of Angular's built-in binding.  Am I going about this the entirely wrong way?

Comment: you create a method in the service that returns the var users this.get = function(){ return users } then in your controller you set $scope.users = usersService.get(); and then your two way data binding will work

Comment: This is the correct way of using `observer pattern` in `angular controller-service` interaction.

Answer (score 3):

Your service is oddly defined, but if you have a return in it you can access it from any controller:

```
app.service('UserService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var users = [];
    this.load = function() {
        var promise = $http.get('users.json')
            .success(function(data){
                // this.users is undefined here
                console.log(users);
                users = data.data;
            }
    };
    return {
        getUsers: function(){
            return users;
        }
    }  
}]);
```

so in your controller, you can use:

`var myUsers = UserService.getUsers();`

**UPDATE**  to use a service correctly here, your service should return a promise and the promise should be accessed in the controller: Here's an example from another answer I gave

```
// your service should return a promise
app.service('PickerService', [$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getFiles: function(){ 
            return $http.get('files.json'); // this returns a promise, the promise is not executed here
        }
    }
}]);
```

then in your controller do this:

```
PickerService.getFiles().then(function(returnValues){ // the promise is executed here as the return values are here
    $scope.myDirectiveData = returnValues.data;
});
```

Comment: I'm new to Angular.  Can you let me know what you mean by oddly defined?

Comment: It's not wrong, but it doesn't return anything, normally when you have a service, it will do something, but as it behaves like a singleton, it is used to store data and return it. Your service runs when it is instantiated, but then does nothing with that data.

Comment: I thought that you only return something if you're using the factory method to generate a service.  app.factory('ServiceName', function() { return {...}}.

Comment: See my updated code. In your example, you are doing an $http call to get data, and you want to access that data in your controller. So that means you need to call it from a controller. If you want to save the data you get back to the service, define a setData function in your service and call it after the .then() once you get data, then it will be accessible via any controller. The service will not broadcast to all your controllers.

Comment: factory and service are VERY similar in how you can use them, but here's a simple article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory to help out

Comment: If I understand you correctly then I would create a service with a local users variable and two methods (load and set).  The load method would use $http.get to load data from the server.  The set method would update the users variable.  The controller would then call load.  Within "then(...)", the controller would BOTH update the $scope AND call the service's set method to update the service's local users value.  That leads to one more question.  How do I automatically update the service's users value whenever $scope.users changes in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

this does not have scope anymore where you are trying to use it do this instead:

```
app.service('UserService', [$http', function($http) {
var users = [];

this.load = function() {
    var promise = $http.get('users.json')
        .success(function(data){
            console.log(users);
        }
};

    promise.then(function() {
    console.log(users);
    });
}]);
```

all local variables to a service should just be vars if you assign them to this as a property than they will be included every time the service is injected into a controller which is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your asking for is a solution along the lines of defining your service like this:

```
angular.module('app')
  .service('User', function($http, $q) {
    var users = null;
    var deferred = $q.defer()

    return {
      getUsers: function() {
        if(users) {
          deferred.resolve(users);
        } else {

          $http.get('users.json');
            .success(function(result) {
              deferred.resolve(result);
            })
            .error(function(error) {
              deferred.reject(error);
            });
        }
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  });
```

Then in one Each controller you would have to do this:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('ACtrl', function($scope, User) {
    User.getUsers().then(function(users) {
      // Same object that's in BCtrl
      $scope.users = users;
    });
  });

angular.module('app')
  .controller('BCtrl', function($scope, User) {
    User.getUsers().then(function(users) {
      // Same object that's in ACtrl
      $scope.users = users;
    });
  });
```

**NOTE:** Because the `deferred.promise` the same promise passed to all controllers, executing `deferred.resolve(users)` in the future will cause all `then` success callbacks in each of your controllers to be called essentially overwriting the old users list.

All operations on the list will be noticed in all controllers because the users array is a shared object at that point. This will only handle updates to the user list/each individual user on the client side of your application. If you want to persist changes to the server, you're going to have to add other $http methods to your service to handle CRUD operations on a user. This can generally be tricky and I highly advise that you check out `ngResource`, which takes care of basic RESTful operations