# Setting local variables as result of Ajax call in Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I'm attempting to create a factory that stores the result of an AJAX call in a variable. So far, I have something along these lines:

```
angular.module('frontApp')
    .factory('myFactory', function(Restangular) {
        var myFactory = function() {
            this.loadedData = [];
            loadData()
        }   

        var loadData = function() {
            Restangular.all('endPoint').customGET('path/run').then(
                function(success) {
                    this.loadedData = success.results;
                }
            );
        }

        return stoppingPatternFactory;
    });
```

But I get an error: `cannot set property 'loadedData' of undefined`.

I understand that the `this` keyword in this context refers to the function context which is why I'm getting the error. The issue is that I cant wrap my head around how to set `this.loadedData` in the first function when the Restangular call is asynchronous. I've tried just making the request in the first function and trying to set the variable in the callback, but I get the same error.

EDIT: I should probably add that I'm trying to create multiple instances of this factory, e.g. `var f = new myFactory()` so that each instance of a directive has its own factory associated with it.

Comment: The use of 'this' in a factory is mis-used. Check this post for proper use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory/24442224#24442224

Comment: Hm - I only briefly looked at this but it seems like they're setting global variables for the Factory which will be available to all instances of the Factory, I need variables that are only available to each instance.

Comment: Factory and Services are singletons - they are global. But you can implement a getInstance() that returns a new object every time its called.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the loadedData in then callback

```
angular.module('frontApp')
.factory('myFactory', function(Restangular) {

    var myFactory = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.loadedData = [];
        loadData().then(function(data){
            self.loadedData =  data;
        })
    }   

    var loadData = function() {
        var restApi = Restangular.all('endPoint')
        return restApi.customGET('path/run').then(
            function(success) {
                return success.results;
            }
        );
    }

    return stoppingPatternFactory;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is "call" or "apply". It will allow you to call a method while setting its "this" reference. You can then save that reference and set its properties anywhere. Something like this should work.

```
angular.module('frontApp')
.factory('myFactory', function(Restangular) {
    var myFactory = function() {
        this.loadedData = [];
        loadData.call(this);
    }   

    var loadData = function() {
        var self = this;
        Restangular.all('endPoint').customGET('path/run').then(
            function(success) {
                self.loadedData = success.results;
            }
        );
    }

    return myFactory;
});
```