# What is the difference between angular.Module.factory and angular.Module.service when creating a service?

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting re-acquainted with angular after a long time away, and (so far) I've discovered two ways to create an angular service. The simplest being this:

```
var app = angular.Module("SomeApp", [])
                 .factory("SomeService", function ($log) {
                    $log.info("Yea beh beh! Dis hea is a service!")
                 });
```

This form of creating a service in angular is documented in [angular.Module.factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#factory). But, you can also see, that on the same page there is another way to create a service, using [angular.Module.service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#service).

Reading the two descriptions, I am unable to understand the differences other than `.service` needs you to explicitly use `new` to instantiate a service, whereas `.factory` implicitly does it for you. I might be wrong here, since I'm unable to understand because I have no clue what a `$get` property is. So, to wrap up:

- What is a `$get` property?
- What is the difference between `.service` and `.factory`?

Lastly, because this bugs me:

- With all `angular.Module.{service, factory, controller}`, the second argument is a `function`. But, for instance, you have put in a list for the second argument in a `controller`, and name its dependencies. Then why is the type taken to be a `function`, rather than `object`? I mean you won't know from the documentation that you can declare dependencies in a list unless you've done a tutorial or something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular.js: service vs provider vs factory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

Answer (score 2):

Both `angular.Module.factory` and `angular.Module.service` are proxies to `angular.Module.provide`. When you give a function to `angular.Module.factory` angular creates the respective service by invoking the function and using its **return value** as the service. On the other hand, when you give a function to `angular.Module.service` angular will treat it as an **constructor** and invoke it with the `new` keyword to create the service.

Thus creating a service with `angular.Module.factory` looks like this:

```
app.factory('MySimpleService', function () {
   return {
      aServiceProperty : 'a property containing a string'
   };
});
```

And creating a similar service with `angular.Module.service` looks like this:

```
app.service('MyOtherSimpleService', function () {
   this.aServiceProperty = 'a property containing a string';
});
```

Comment: In what contexts would you use one over the other. To me, it feels as though I would almost always use `.factory` over `.service`.

Comment: Generally, I use `.factory` to creat a constructor (by returning a function) and `.service` to create singleton objects (by writing properties and methods to `this`, or returning an instance of a constructor)

Comment: I don't see any particular advantage of the one over the other. I think it's more a convention you should define in your team. I often use them as @SpencerAlger suggests.

Answer (score 1):

1. The definition of the $get propery can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide)
2. Looks like this question has already been [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory). I am unable to comment, so I posted an answer.