# Why is an angularjs factory called a 'factory'?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

What, if anything, does it have to do with the factory pattern?

Or if nothing, then why is it called a factory? It seems more like a singleton to me.

Comment: Both `.service` and `.factory` create a singleton. Here's more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory

Comment: ok so why is it called a factory then?

Comment: http://iffycan.blogspot.in/2013/05/angular-service-or-factory.html refer this & http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/PxdSP/14/

Comment: @richard, because it creates an instance within the `.factory` function and returns it. `.service` on the other hand news up a service.

Comment: @New Dev but what does that mean it "news up a service"? It's not a singleton then right? You got a new instance?

Comment: No, you'll still get a singleton.

Comment: So then I don't know what it means when you say it news up an instance. It's not new...:-(

Comment: @richard, read again the link I gave you and you'll understand what I mean by "news up".

Comment: Because it is a factory, as in factory pattern.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that a `factory` can be used to create factory functions

```
app.factory('MyFactory', function() {
  // The returned function is available by injecting MyFactory
  // into other components
  return function() {
    return 'Something created by the factory';
  };
});
```

This can be used, for example, in a controller

```
app.controller('MyController', function(MyFactory) {
  var myObj = MyFactory();
  // myObj is 'Something created by the factory'
});
```

(You can do something like this using `service` as well. I think you just have to live with the fact there is almost complete overlap between what you can do with `factory` and `service`)

Comment: Thanks Michael. I think it's an unfortunate choice of words for them to name it a factory.