# Different between myApp.factory and myApp.service into angular application

Tags: angularjs

What is different between myApp.factory and myApp.service in angular web application. please explain use of both in logical way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular.service vs angular.factory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory)

Answer (score 0):

Source:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15666049/1632286

From the AngularJS mailing list I got an amazing thread that explains service vs factory vs provider and their injection usage. Compiling the answers:

Services

Syntax: module.service( 'serviceName', function ); 
Result: When declaring serviceName as an injectable argument you will be provided with an instance of the function. In other words new FunctionYouPassedToService().

Factories

Syntax: module.factory( 'factoryName', function ); 
Result: When declaring factoryName as an injectable argument you will be provided with the value that is returned by invoking the function reference passed to module.factory.

Providers

Syntax: module.provider( 'providerName', function ); 
Result: When declaring providerName as an injectable argument you will be provided with ProviderFunction().$get(). The constructor function is instantiated before the $get method is called - ProviderFunction is the function reference passed to module.provider.