# angularjs service,provider and factory?

Tags: angularjs

I am little bit confusing on this service,provider and factory. What are the differences between AngularJS module's service, provider and factory?please tell and give examples on this

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15666048/2451726

Comment: It has been well explained here.
[Link][1]y


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory

Comment: Look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this.
this tutorial may help you:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/