# Can an Angular controller bind to multiple parts of a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-controller

Suppose that I've written a web page that requires the user to key in data into forms.  Suppose that there are two parts of the page that are completely separate in the DOM, yet are logically related.  I need to bind them to a single model.

The first (bad) solution I can think of is to completely restructure the page so that everything to be bound to the model is contained in a single `<div>` element (or perhaps even put the controller on the `<body>` element).

Another solution might be to bind the inputs to a object that could be made a member of two different controllers, but that sounds like a bit of a kludge.

Suppose the HTML looks like this:

```
<input ng-model='data1' />
<div>
    <!-- something complicated -->
</div>
<input ng-model='data2' />
```

Comment: Store your model into a service, and inject it into both of your controllers. That's not a kludge, it's the correct way to do it.

Comment: What Blackhole said. Services are singletons in your app, and their data will be consistent across your controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a shared service and inject into both controllers. This can be achieved by either the `factory` or `service` pattern. See SO post [angular.service vs angular.factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory) for some insight on the difference/similarity between the two.

This is the Angular way to do this. See the [AngularJS services docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) for more information. A simple example may include...

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlA"></div>
    <div ng-controller="ctrlB"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
app.service('sharedService', [function () {
    this.someValue = 'yo!'
}]);

app.controller('ctrlB', ['$scope', 'sharedService', function($scope, sharedService) {
    console.log(sharedService.someValue) // yo!
}]);

app.controller('ctrlA', ['$scope', 'sharedService', function($scope, sharedService) {
    console.log(sharedService.someValue) // yo!
}]);
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/atwzf4bc/)

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Can you give an example of what the example would look like if there were a text field in each div?

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon sure of course. Just bind a model to the service value. Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oo62ouvc/) out. Let me know if helpful?

Comment: Thank you.  I will try this in the morning :-)

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon Have you made any forward progress on this?