# AngularJS : share common factory to create a new object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

My application has two execution paths.

```
Root
 |
 |---Tool1 --> T1Page 1
 |         --> T1Page 2
 |
 |---Tool2 --> T2Page 1
 |         --> T2Page 2
 |
 |----Factory (F)
```

Here **T1Page2** and and **T2Page2** are having similar UI elements and I have defined a factory for that. Now the problem is, if user first start Tool1 and then navigate to Tool2, in **T2Page2** it displays the values selected in **T1Page2** . This is obviously because of the singleton injection in the controller. How can i make sure that Angular returns a new factory object when user comes to **T2Page2**.

One solution I can think of is to add a clean up method in the factory and call it whenever user starts the **T2Page2**. But that doesnt sounds good to me.

Factory

```
(function () {
var serviceId = 'setUp';
angular.module('app').factory(serviceId , ['common', 'datacontext']);
function setUp(common,datacontext){
var vm = this;
vm.name='';
vm.address='';
return init();

 function init() {
      return vm;
  }
}
}());
```

T1Page2 Controller 1

```
(function () {    
    var controllerId = 'T1Page2';
    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['common', 'datacontext', 'setUp', T1Page2]);

function T1Page2(common, datacontext, setup) {
   //code omitted
  }
}());
```

T2Page2 Controller 2

```
(function () {    
    var controllerId = 'T2Page2';
    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['common', 'datacontext', 'setUp', T2Page2]);

function T2Page2(common, datacontext, setup) {
   //need a new setUp object here. 
   // rest of the code omitted
  }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there are two possible solutions to your question.

Solution 1

Use an Angular Service rather than a Factory. While a factory maintains a persistent state (it is new'ed when the module is loaded), a service returns a constructor function for you to new as many times as you'd like (you can create a new service for each Tool).

Sample Service:

```
angular.module('app').service('MyService',
  function () {
    this.name = '';
    this.address = '';
  }
]);
```

Utilizing a Service within a controller (for example)

```
$scope.myService = new MyService();
```

Solution 2

Create 2 factories.  One factory for Tool1 and another for Tool2.

Solution 2 might be easier in your case since you want a service (used in the general sense here) to be used by one group of pages, while a second group of pages needs a different persistent state object.

Comment: @sflectche thanks. I will try first solution, otherwise i will be duplicating lots of code.

Comment: if i dont inject and use $scope.service = new MyService()'; it says myService is not defined. If I inject myService, it says "Object is not a function".

Comment: Sorry @JenorD - I had a typo.  You were correct, it should be `$scope.service`.  I just updated my answer.

Comment: `service` and `factory` are the other way around. A service is instantiated once and shared everywhere it is injected; a factory is a function that is invoked whenever you need a new instance.

Comment: Hey @Sly_cardinal - I do think there is a lot of confusion about this (and [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) don't exactly help), this [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory) provides a good explanation about the service being new'ed and the factory being invoked.

Comment: @sflectche, it says all providers in AngularJS (value, constant, services, factories) are singletons? So I will end up in the same situation even if I use the service. If user opened Tool1Page2, and then navigate back to Tool2Page2, then I will get the same object in Tool1Page2 injected in Tool2Page2. Isnt that so?

Comment: When you `new` a service, you are creating a fresh and distinct copy of that service. Each `new`'ed service will contain a state that is distinct from other `new`'ed instances of that same service.