# AngularJS : Access an object from any controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

What is the best way to store a "user" object that is accessible across all controllers in an Angular application?

I also have a function that fetches & sets the user.

**Option 1: $rootScope**

At first I was just setting `$rootScope.user = myUser`. Then in every control I could use $rootScope. This was fine, until I ended up with a lot of duplicate code since I had to check if it existed at the start of each controller.

```
// At the start of each controller

if (!$rootScope.user) {
  // fetch and set user
}
```

**Option 2: Angular service?**

**Option 3: Angular factory?**

References:
[angular.service vs angular.factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory)

Comment: Missing a fundamental part of $scope inheritance. If it's on $rootScope...$scope in controller will already inherit that property [ultra simple demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/4TfpZzSaACDD2odFCA3s). In other words when you were injecting it and adding it to $scope...it was already there and available. I'm not saying this is how it should be done...more just pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl - I understand that part :) But since a person can open the app on many different controllers, I always need the check.

Comment: back to the question...if using UI router can add a resolve to abstract state that is parent of all states that require auth. Then you only need a check one place for many routes. Just wire it up to your Auth service

Comment: That's a really interesting solution. Let me look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a factory over a service, or $rootScope.

As Ed pointed out below, both a service and a  factory are singletons.

$rootScope, as the name implies is the root of all scopes in an angularjs  application.

Here is something for reference: http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/12/angularjs-service-vs-factory/

Comment: This is incorrect. A factory also returns a singleton. Services and factories are very similar but are declared with a slightly different syntax.

Comment: Your are correct, I swapped em accidentally. Corrected above.

Comment: Still wrong ;) service creates a new instance once, but returns that same instance subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a SPA and not creating a scope without parent then use rootScope it will work like a charm.