# Should I store a firebase ref instance in $rootScope, or create a new one in each controller?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am using Angular and firebase for the backend to build an app. Many of my controllers will be working with firebase in someway. Should I just keep a ref to my firebase instance in the $rootScope or create a new one in each controller.

```
    //at the top of each controller?        
    var ref = new Firebase(firebaseUrl);
```

Or

```
    //set this once in app launch and use everywhere else
    $rootScope.fbRef = new Firebase(firebaseUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is "neither" an acceptable answer? It's more common to create a data service (store) and inject that service into controllers as needed.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, and a service is only initialized once, then that instance is injected into each controller. Or do I have that backwards with a factory?

Comment: Services and factories both are singletons in Angular, and both must be injected into the controllers where you want to use them.

Good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21900284/1072176