# Passing an array from service to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, service

I cannot seem to figure out how to pass an array from service to a controller.

I have a simple service

```
.service('test', function() {
    var array = []

    return array;
})
```

And a controller where I call this function when a button is pressed

```
$scope.testArray = function() {
    $scope.test = test.array;

    console.log("test: ", $scope.test);
};
```

I get an error test is undefined. Can anyone explain to me please why this doesn't work and how to fix it? I tried storing that array in a separate object but no luck either. THanks

Comment: Are you injecting your service into your controller?

Comment: Yes, this is my controller -> .controller('TestCtrl', ['test', function(test) { <- there is a lot more data but I omitted that as I don't think it would be relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(See also: [this SO question about Angular providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory))

A `service` should put properties directly on `this`.  So instead of

```
.service('test', function() {
    var array = [];

    return array; 
})
```

try

```
.service('test', function() {
    this.array = [];
})
```

(code style notwithstanding; many would suggest preferring function access over direct object access)

```
.service('test', function() {
    var array = [];
    this.getArray = function(){
        return array;
    };
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I put it like you showed in the last example and then just tried console.log(test.getArray()); and it works! Can you tell me why wasn't my solution working and this function solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Just change `test.array`with `test`:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/s1Lhbj97/)

```
.controller('youCtrl', ['$scope', 'test', function ($scope, test) {
    $scope.testArray = function() {
       $scope.test = test;

       console.log("test: ", $scope.test);
    };
});
```

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work for me. I might be tripping out already, it is a part of an Ionic app if that might matter.

Comment: Thanks guys now it works too, this one return object to me and the suggestion above the array so both are good. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the `array` variable to your `service`.

```
angular.module('moduleName').service('test', function() {
  this.array = [];
});
```

Inject your `service` into your `controller`.

```
angular.module('moduleName').controller('controllerName', function(test) {
  $scope.test = test.array;

  console.log("test: ", $scope.test);
});
```