# Sharing data among controllers not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to share data between 2 controllers that are on 2 different pages, but it's not working as expected.

page1.html:

```
<form ng-controller="FormController">
<input ng-model="user.email">
</form>
```

page1controller.js:

```
 app.controller("FormController", ['$scope', '$http', '$window', 'UserEmailService', function($scope, $http, $window, UserEmailService) {
  // Code logic here
  console.log($scope.user.email) // Code outputs a string here
  UserEmailService.setEmail($scope.user.email);
  $window.location.href = "/page2"; // Redirects to page2.html after logic completes
}]);
```

page2.html:

```
<div controller="SomeController">
<p> Hi, your e-mail is {{ email }} </p>
</div>
```

SomeController.js:

```
  app.controller("SomeController", ['$scope', 'UserEmailService', function($scope, UserEmailService) {
    console.log(UserEmailService.getEmail()); // outputs undefined
    $scope.email = UserEmailService.getEmail();
  }]);
```

UserEmailService.js

```
app.service("UserEmailService", function(){
    var email = [];

    var setEmail = function(val) {
      email.push(val);
    };

    var getEmail = function() {
      return email.pop();
    };

    return {
      setEmail : setEmail,
      getEmail : getEmail
    };


  });
```

I'm trying to get the user e-mail from page1.html and displaying it on page2.html, but it always comes up as undefined on page2.html. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you initializing your user object anywhere? That's the only reason I can think of why you're seeing some stuff being outputed on console.log.

Comment: what are you using for routing?

Answer (score 1):

In `FormController`, `$window.location.href` will cause a full page reload, which make your service state reset. Try `$location.url('')` to navigate to that route. It does not cause a full page reload.

If you want your data available after a full page reload. You should use something like localstorage instead.

---

Use factory instead of service. For more information [angular.service vs angular.factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory)

```
app.factory("UserEmailService", function(){
  var email = [];

  var setEmail = function(val) {
    email.push(val);
  };

  var getEmail = function() {
    return email.pop();
  };

  return {
    setEmail : setEmail,
    getEmail : getEmail
  };

});
```

Comment: Still not working, getEmail function still returns an undefined value.

Answer (score 0):

In your listening controller (SomeController)

```
$scope.$watch(function () { 
    return UserEmailService.getEmail();
},
function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue){
        $scope.user.email = newValue;
    }
});
```

So that your final code looks like

```
    app.controller("SomeController", ['$scope', 'UserEmailService', function($scope, UserEmailService) {
        $scope.$watch(function () { return UserEmailService.getEmail();},
            function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== oldValue){
                    $scope.user.email = newValue;
                }
        });
    }]);
```