# Separate common parts of controller into a common controller

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, controllers

I'm developing an web app using AngularJS with uiRouter. I developed my route configuration as follows:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    var module = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial', 'ui.router']);

    function Config($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider.state('Home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/homeview.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        }).state('Table', {
            url: '/tableview',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/tableview.html',
            controller: 'tableCtrl'
        }).state('List', {
            url: '/listview',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/listview.html',
            controller: 'listCtrl'
        }).state('New', {
            url: '/new',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/new.html',
            controller: 'newCtrl'
        }).state('Edit', {
            url: '/edit/:index',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/edit.html',
            controller: 'editCtrl'
        });
    }
    Config.$inject = ["$urlRouterProvider", "$stateProvider"];

    module.config(Config);
}());
```

The thing in some controller passed to the view the code is duplicated, so I would like to know if there is a way to pass 2 controllers to the view at the same time or if there is a way to create a separate file with that specific part of the duplicated controller and pass it as Dependency Injection in the desired controllers.

Comment: You can use angular services/factories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two controllers linked to a uiRouter route. But you could certainly make a service or factory that includes your universal functionality. (See [angular.service vs angular.factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory) for more research.)

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])
app.service('myFunctions',function() {
  this.addNumbers = function(a,b) {
    // calculate some stuff
    return a+b;
  }
}
app.controller('myController',function(myFunctions){
  myFunctions.addNumbers(2,2); // 4
})
```