# How do we call a function type returned by a Service in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, service, call

Well, I was clarifying my doubts on Angular Servcies and factories and came across a tutorial which describes it on the basis of return types.

Currently I have following :

```
angular.module("Training").service("Service", tryDis);
angular.module("Training").factory("Factory", tryDis);

function tryDis(){
    console.log("trying..");
    return "tried"; 
}
```

and then I have :

```
angular.module("Training").controller("Ctrl1", function($scope,Service, Factory){

    $scope.serviceData = Service;
    $scope.factoryData = Factory;

});
```

As the tutorial says service returns the whole function itself, while factory returns the string "tried". This was very well.

Now my point is if I have a function type returned and since it do not take any arguments too, I shall still somehow get the function executed right. So that somehow I get "tried" from Service too.

Referring to JS function.prototype.call(), I tried

```
angular.module("Training").controller("Ctrl1", function($scope,Service, Factory){

    $scope.serviceData = this.call(Service);//also call(Service)
    $scope.factoryData = Factory;

});
```

This doesn't seem to work. 
How do I get the string "tried" in above case.??

Note: I am pretty familiar with use of 'this' while writing services. But here my question is not just regarding services in Angular, rather its about calling a returned function in JS

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory

Answer (score 0):

You must define the service like this:

```
angular.module("Training").service("Service", tryDis);

function tryDis(){
    this.output=function(){
        console.log("trying..");
        return "tried";
    };
}
```

and then get the returned value in your controller like this:

```
angular.module("Training").controller("Ctrl1", function($scope,Service, Factory){

    $scope.serviceData = Service.output();

});
```

Comment: Hi Amin, I am pretty familiar with your way of writing services. But here my question is not just regarding services in Angular, rather its about calling a returned function in JS

Comment: this is the idea of using a Service in general (although the same outcome can be achieved using factory) this is one of the differences between a Service and a Factory, Services do not return a value in their global scopes

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do that you need to return a function from the service:

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', function(testService) {
    console.log(testService())
  })
  .service('testService', function() {
      return function() {
        return 'tried';
      };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl"></div>
```

Comment: Tried this already: this doesn't work. Error: Service is not a function

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari You said *"if I have a function type returned"* so I thought service is returning a function. It should actually return a function. see update.

Comment: service uses `this`...no real need to return anything. Answer looks more like a factory

Comment: @ T J : I completely get ur point, and I am aware of the way u modified my function to return a function. But the whole point asking this question was to display the difference between a factory and a Service using a common function as in Original Post. Does this mean, I can't retrieve the desired output using my original case

Comment: @charlietfl it is supposed to, but this is the answer for the question *""How do I get the string "tried" in above case.??" "*

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari services is supposed to be used like a class constructor, whos instances have properties and methods, not for returning a tiny string. My answer answers the question you were asking, which was *"How do I get the string "tried" in above case.??"*

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari service and factory are slightly different so not sure why you want a common function to use for both...especially considering they are singeletons

Comment: @T J : Basically my question was how do I get the string "tried" from what service has returned me. Leaving apart Angular for a moment, I wanted to know if I have a function reference returned in a variable, how do I execute it in JS environment. If I see the value of $scope.serviceData in console it is like tryDis(), which basically means it is pointing to a function