# Simple angular service not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create an angular service but it is not working. I have tried numeros things and looked all over.Please help

```
 //service 

 angular
    .module('RDash')
    .factory('googleLogin', googleLogin); 

function googleLogin() 
{
    this.testFunc = function () 
    {
        console.log("THIS IS A TEST SERVICE");
    }
};
```

Below: tryoing to call service test func

```
//controller

angular
    .module('RDash')
    .controller('ComposeCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope','$http','googleLogin', ComposeCtrl]);

function ComposeCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $http, googleLogin) {
    console.log("ComposeCTRL active");

    googleLogin.testFunc(); // this doesnt work, error: "main.min.js:2 Error: [$injector:undef] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/undef?p0=googleLogin"
```

I feel like the issue is with injecting i just dont know where. Please help thanks

Comment: factory needs to return the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factory needs to return the function refrence and you need to declare variable `testFunc` (answer to why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory)):

**Update** working snippet.

```js
angular.module('RDash', []);
angular
  .module('RDash')
  .factory('googleLogin', googleLogin);

function googleLogin() {
  var testFunc = function() {
    console.log("THIS IS A TEST SERVICE");
  }
  return {
    testFunc : testFunc
  }
};

angular
  .module('RDash')
  .controller('ComposeCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', 'googleLogin', ComposeCtrl]);

function ComposeCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $http, googleLogin) {
  console.log("ComposeCTRL active");

  googleLogin.testFunc();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="RDash" ng-controller="ComposeCtrl"></div>
```

```js
angular
   .module('RDash')
   .factory('googleLogin', googleLogin);

 function googleLogin() {

   var testFunc = function() {
     console.log("THIS IS A TEST SERVICE");
   }

   return {
     testFunc: testFunc
   }

 };
```

Comment: hi, i tried that but it still thrws "testFunc Is not defined" from controller

Comment: @LaurenL : Updated the answer with working snippet. Take a look

Comment: it did! Thank you for your help and thourough explanation. Marked as sovled :) @A.J

Comment: whats the difference between using `this` and `var` ? @A.J

Comment: @LaurenL : Apologises for the late response. it is all about best practice . If you attach variable to this then you need to return this.[var name] . and it works. In short it is all about best practise .