# How do I call $resource service from controller in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ngresource

This is get service function where I am calling the API

```
    .factory('Report', function($resource, API_URL) {
       return $resource(API_URL  + 
       'security/:userId/1498780800000/listOfDeliveries', {

      userId : '@userId',
      expected : '@expected',
      arg1 : '@arg1'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  })
```

In the app.js I have this below controller

```
    .controller('ReportsController', function($scope, $rootScope, 
     ProfileData, $state, $timeout, Report) {


})
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to [check how angular factory & service work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory)

Your factory return a $resource, so read the [doc about $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

> A resource "class" object with methods for the default set of resource
>   actions optionally extended with custom actions. The default set
>   contains these actions:

```
{ 
   'get':    {method:'GET'},
   'save':   {method:'POST'},
   'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
   'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
   'delete': {method:'DELETE'}
};
```

So, you can use theses methods: Report.get(), Report.save(), Report.query(), Report.remove(), Report.delete()

In addition there are custom method you defined: Report.update()

And you can pass userId as params so:

`Report.get({userId: 1234});` will call a GET request to: `API_URL+'security/1234/1498780800000/listOfDeliveries`

(`expected` and `args1` are not in url so I dont think you need them)

**What's returning Report.get() ?**

> Class actions return empty instance (with additional properties below). Instance actions return promise of the action

So `Report.get(...)` is returning a promise, you will get data by:

```
Report.get(...).then(function(data) {
  $scope.requestData = data;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Fetra.. Its working .. may i know how to pass this timestamp parameter dynamically

Comment: yes, you can add a params like userId or expected:
return $resource(API_URL  + 
       'security/:userId/:timestamp/listOfDeliveries', {

      userId : '@userId',
      timestamp: '@timestamp',....

Comment: I have added param timestamp.. I am new to hybrid app development. can you please explain me why this below code is not working.

Comment: $scope.requestData = {
      expectedDateDate : '1498780800000'
        };
   $scope.residents = Report.get({userId: Safence_App.userId},{timestamp: requestData.expectedDateDate});

Comment: It's not from hybrid app it's angular. You should really read the the link I give you from $resource, it will return a promise, and there are example from the official site I gave you. I'm editing the answer to help you.