# AngularJS) TypeError : serviceName.functionName() is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I wanna make "Go back when cancel btn clicked" function.

This is view code

```
<div ng-controller="goodCtrl">    
<button class="btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

And this is Js code

1) controller

```
function goodCtrl($scope, $log, goodService)
    $scope.cancel = function(){
        $log.debug("goodCtrl - cancel");
        goodService.cancel($scope);
    };
```

2) service

```
function goodService($log, $state)
    var methods = {
       cancel: function($scope) {
           $log.debug("goodService - cancel");
           $state.go('goback');
       }
    }
```

3) module

```
angular
    .module('goodmodule')
    .controller('goodCtrl', goodCtrl)
    .service('goodService', goodService)
```

But I got this problem

> TypeError : `serviceName.functionName()` is not a function

Though there are so many controls, services, methods written like that, the service and controller that I added is unavailable.
What is it that I missed?

Comment: Is that literally the error message? Don't see anything in your code that looks like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angularjs, to define a **service**, you have to assign properties in **this** keyword within **service** function. Because in angular js constructor function is used to create a custom service.Below code is your updated service code.

```
    function goodService($log, $state) {
    this.cancel = function ($scope) {
        $log.debug("goodService - cancel");
        $state.go('goback');
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved problem! it occurs because of not returning methods. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you have defined `service` register methods to be exposed using using `this`

```
function goodService($log, $state) {
    this.cancel = function ($scope) {
        $log.debug("goodService - cancel");
        $state.go('goback');
    }
}
```

I would also recommend you to use [Dependency Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation), Here I have used `$inject` property annotation

```
 goodCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$log', 'goodService'];
 goodService.$inject = ['$log', '$state'];
```

Comment: I solved problem! it occurs because of not returning methods. thanks!

Comment: @zzangs33, then you should define it as a `factory` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory