# Using instantiated object reference within the controller

Tags: javascript, object, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how I could use one JavaScript object instantiation across multiple controllers in AngularJS. Try to envisage the following scenario:

```
var objTemplate = new templateObject();
objTemplate.init();

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {

    objTemplate.slidePage();

});
```

Obviously the objTemplate.initialise(); doesn't work within the controller and I'm not quite sure how to do it.

EDIT:

Thanks for the answer @Atrix - it looks like the way forward will be to create a new service and move all of the functionality from the JavaScript object to it - then use the service to perform all these operations.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work in the controller?

Comment: Not sure why - but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a factory in order to instantiate your object once and access it from all controllers.

For more details about factory and service and also examples check [@matys84pl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1843005/matys84pl) & [@JustGoscha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813142/justgoscha) answers [about services & factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory)

Comment: added links to other answers which have more details