# could not get the property value of my object in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get `undefined` whenever I get the value of a property of an object.

```
function run(id){
   var report = services.getReportInfo(id);

   var childReport = {
       id: newGuid(),
       parentId: report.id, // i get undefined
       reportPath: report.path  // i get undefined
   };

   ...
}
```

**services.js**

```
angular.module('project.services').factory('services', function(){

   var reports = [
      {
         ....
      },
      {
         ....
      }
   ];

   function getReportInfo(id){
      var report = reports.filter(function(element){
          return element.id === id;
      });
   };

   return{
      getReportInfo: getReportInfo
   };
}
```

Whenever I put breakpoint on my `var report = services.getReportInfo(id)` it could contains the correct values for each property of the my report object. However, when I get the report.id or report.path, I get undefined value.

**--Edited--**

Oh, I know now where I got wrong.

The getReportInfo function returns an array and I'm accessing the properties without telling from what index should it get the values for the said properties.

```
function run(id){
    var report = services.getReportInfo(id);

    var childReport = {
       id: newGuid(),
       parentId: report[0].id,
       reportPath: report[0].path 
    };

    ...
}
```

I placed static index 0, since I know that the array will always have a length of 1.

Comment: Where do you inject the service inside the run function? Is the run function inside of a controller?

Comment: Yes Sanjo, the run function is inside a controller. I just didn't include it to lessen the code written above

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning anything from the `.factory` method and the getReportInfo is also not returning anything.  For what you are trying to do, try to use `.service` method:

```
angular.module('project.services').service('services', function(){

   var reports = [
      {
         ....
      },
      {
         ....
      }
   ];

   this.getReportInfo = function (id){
      var report = reports.filter(function(element){
          return element.id === id;
      });
      return report;
   }
}
```

Here is a good explanation on how to use `.factory` and `.service`:
[Confused about Service vs Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory)

Answer (score 0):

Two immediate issues with the code I can see:

1) Your factory function needs to return a value or constructor function. Right now your code is not initializing the factory to any value.

2) Your getReportInfo function also doesn't return a value, yet you are assigning the function result to a variable.

Read more here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for your answer :) as for #2, it does return a value. When I put a breakpoint and check the report variable, I see the values I needed.