# Angular service variables not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following service (pseudo code)

```
app.service('user', function($http) {
    function login(email, password, callback) {
        // login user
        // set isLoggedIn to true
        // assign the returned user object to userData
        // issue callback
    };

    return {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        userData: null,
        login: login
    };
});
```

Here is my login controller:

```
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $http, $location, user) {
    user.login($scope.email, $scope.password, function(isSuccess, data, status) {
        if (isSuccess) { $scope.onSuccessfulLogin(); }
        else { $scope.loginStatusMessage = data; }
    });

    $scope.onSuccessfulLogin = function() {
        $location.path('/someOtherPage');
    };
});
```

And here is the controller used in `/someOtherPage`

```
app.controller('SomeOtherPageController', function($scope, $http, $modal, user) {
    // lots of stuff in here
    // I put a breakpoint on the first line and user.isLoggedIn is false
    // even though it was definitely set to true when the user logged in.
)};
```

Once the callback has been issued when login in using the `user` service, if the login was successful the user is taken to a different page with a different controller, where the above `user` service is injected. The problem is that if the login is successful, although I can see the `isLoggedIn` and `userData` variables being assigned correctly, in the new controller they remain `false` and `null` respectively.

Have I missed something here ? I need the values to be the same whenever `user` is injected like a singleton.

Thanks

Comment: So I see you decided the service was the answer over the factory...can't say I agree but I guess it's up to u.

Comment: @StenMuchow - coming from a .net background this seems like a cleaner solution to me. I'm not sure if there are any benefits to your solution over the one I chose, but i'm purely going on that basis.

Comment: ok... check out the same thing in my edited answer. The thing i dont like about the other answer is the use of the that variable, but i am just picky...

Comment: and actually the code was incorrect up until i just edited it. Which i notice u cant actually see. but he forgot the function keyword that this.login needs to be set to...

Comment: @StenMuchow I noticed the missing function keyword also. I think both answers are viable - I will play around some more tonight when I get home from work. I'm .net developer by day, javascript by night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a service, not a factory.  A service is returns an instance of your function.  Which means once injected everyone is going to be using the same instance.  In your case you are using a factory(you have updated it since I posted my answer), and every time its injected it returns the value returned from the function.  The best SO post on this is here [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

I tend to use services when I want to drive this point home.  I want people to know if they inject this, everyone is going to be sharing the same object.  I often use it with Cache's and Users.

```
app.service('user', function($http) {
    var that = this;

    this.isLoggedIn = false;
    this.login = function(email, password, callback) {
       that.isLoggedIn = true;
       // login user
       // set isLoggedIn to true
       // assign the returned user object to userData
       // issue callback
    };
    return this;
})
```

Comment: Hey Nix, I tried it with a service and it's still the same problem. Any thoughts ? Thanks.

Comment: No matter how you construct a service it will always be a singleton. So this is not a issue.

Comment: Nix - added more code, maybe you could take a look ?

Comment: @Nix - I tried this and it's the same problem. I started a bounty .. any other thoughts ?

Comment: @Nix - sorry for spamming. I noticed that when I do this, and put a breakpoint into the login function, `this` is actually a window object, and none of the service variables have been defined. Does this point to the issue ? Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50818/discussion-between-nix-and-sten-muchow)

Comment: @dfsq when he originally posted he had `app.factory(` .  He has since updated it.

Comment: I know, factory also is going to create a singleton. As well as service.

Answer (score 1):

Actually all services in angular are singletons. Check this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory) for more info. Anywho, onto your problem, and this directly from Angular docs:

> Angular services are:
>
> Lazily instantiated – Angular only instantiates a service when an
>   application component depends on it.
>
> Singletons – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance
>   generated by the service factory.

You should be using a factory as you just need to recreate the revealing module pattern, which Angular implements through the factory, the service is a constructor function.

Both of these are besides the point that your service is simply returning null and false for both values and no matter what you change them to internally in the service the values will always be null and false. You are returning an object so you need to wire the key value pair up correctly.

```
app.factory('user', function($http) {
    var service = {};

    service.userData = null;
    service.isLoggedIn = false;
    service.login = function(email, password, callback) {
        // login user
        // set isLoggedIn to true
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        // assign the returned user object to userData
        this.userData = someValue;
        // issue callback
    } 

    return service;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are returning an object that is instantiated with null and false:

```
return {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        userData: null,
        login: login
    };
```

It should be returning another closure variable.

```
 return {
            isLoggedIn: myIsLoggedIn,
            userData: myUserData,
            login: login
        };
```

Where `myUserData` and `myIsLoggedIn` are set in the `login` function. Or another route is to return methods that return those values as @Sten mentioned.

Comment: It was my first suggestion, but after a chat I showed the getter and setter version as well...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in the service, but in the controller: probably you have a scope property set to isLoggeIn value, something like that:

```
$scope.isLoggedIn = user.isLoggedIn
```

but, without a watcher to user service value, your scope property will not change its value.
Can you post controller code?

Comment: Hi wilver - I added in more code and details into the question. Maybe you could take a look if you get a chance ? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post more code on how you use user service in your controller? All in the code you posted seems correct...

Comment: I believe that your 'SomeOtherAppController' controller initialization run before login service complete and your scope is not watching for update. try to put a watcher on user service property, something like this: https://github.com/williamverdolini/discitur-web/blob/master/app/modules/user/UserNavBarCtrl.js#L68

Comment: Yes I tried this - at no point is the user seen as logged in. Even when I go back to the login controller after logging in it is back to false .. no idea why that would happen.

Comment: so, the problem is in login method and how it updates the data, try to use var _user = {isLoggedIn:false,....} return _user; and in login method change _user properties