# What do factory, service and dependency injection exactly mean in angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, terminology, sample

I am a little confused about the following Angular.js concepts:

- factory
- service
- dependency injection

Can anyone brief me on each one with a simple example or explanation? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hope helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory/13763886#13763886

Answer (score 0):

These concepts are part of JavaScript core.

`RegExp` is a Factory:

```js
console.log(RegExp("[0-9]") );
console.log(RegExp("[a-z]") );
console.log(RegExp("[A-Z]") );
console.log(RegExp("[0-9a-zA-Z]") );
```

`Math` is a Service:

```js
console.log(Math.PI);
console.log(Math.round(Math.PI));
console.log(Number(Math.random() * 1000).toFixed());
console.log(Number(Math.random() * 10).toPrecision(2));
console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1);
```

`call` and `apply` are Dependency Injection:

```js
"use strict";

var foo = {
    min: function min(array) {
        return Math.min.apply(Math, array);
    },

    max: function max(array) {
        return Math.max.apply(Math, array);
    }
};

var bar = foo.min([1,2,3]);
var baz = foo.max([1,2,3]);

console.log("bar: " + bar);
console.log("baz: " + baz);
```

**References**

- [Meta Programming in ES6 using Symbols | DotNetCurry](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/javascript/1265/metaprogramming-javascript-using-es6-symbols)
- [John Resig - Fast JavaScript Max/Min](https://johnresig.com/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/)
- [You're Already Using Dependency Injection - Modern Perl Programming](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2011/08/youre-already-using-dependency-injection.html)
- [Simple Dependency Injection in Ruby - Sebastian's Blog](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/09/25/simple-dependency-injection/)
- [SAPUI5: JavaScript Coding Guidelines](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/eded636b85584cd586b1fe231d2b5dac.html)
- [Functional JavaScript, Part 3: apply, call, and the arguments object](http://www.intelligiblebabble.com/functional-javascript-part-3-apply-call-and-the-arguments-object)