# AngularJS services vs factory advantages and shortcomings

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

Am sure this is bothering some beginners, What are the advantages and shortcomings of AngularJS services over factories and vice-verse?

Comment: Please do at least _some_ research: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Service** vs **Factory**

---

[image]

The difference between factory and service is just like the difference between a `function` and an `object`

**Factory Provider**

- Gives us the function's return value ie. You just create an object, add properties to it, then return that same object.When you pass this service into your controller, those properties on the object will now be available in that controller through your factory. (Hypothetical Scenario)
- Singleton
- Reusable components
- Can use other dependencies
- Usually used when the service instance requires complex creation logic
- Used for non configurable services
- If you're using an object, you could use the factory provider.
- Syntax: `module.factory('factoryName', function);`

**Service Provider**

- Gives us the instance of a function (object)- You just  instantiated with the ‘new’ keyword and you’ll add properties to ‘this’ and the service will return ‘this’.When you pass the service into your controller, those properties on ‘this’ will now be available on that controller through your service. (Hypothetical Scenario)
- Singleton and will only be created once
- Reusable components
- Dependencies are injected as constructor arguments
- Used for simple creation logic
- If you're using a class you could use the service provider
- Syntax: `module.service(‘serviceName’, function);`

In below example I have define `MyService` and `MyFactory`. Note how in `.service` I have created the service methods using `this.methodname.` In `.factory` I have created a factory object and assigned the methods to it.

**AngularJS .service**

---

```
module.service('MyService', function() {

    this.method1 = function() {
       //..
       return functionValue;
    }

    this.method2 = function() {
       //..
       return functionValue;
    }
});
```

**AngularJS .factory**

---

```
module.factory('MyFactory', function() {

    var factory = {}; 

    factory.method1 = function() {
       //..
    }

    factory.method2 = function() {
       //..
    }

    return factory;
});
```

---

Also Take a look at this beautiful stuffs

**[Confused about service vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory)**

[**AngularJS Factory, Service and Provider**](http://blogs.clevertech.biz/startupblog/angularjs-factory-service-provider)

[**Angular.js: service vs provider vs factory?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)