# Are Angular.js services singletons or created each time?

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

I am confused about something regarding factories and services for Angular.js.

In this question:

[angular.service vs angular.factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory)

It says that services are created with the `new` keyword.

While in this question:

[Confused about Service vs Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory)

It says that services are "singletons".

**My questions are:**

When you add a 'service' as a dependency injection argument to another module, does Angular create a new service each time? Or is it really singleton (as in one will be created, and then provide that specific instance everywhere)?

Comment: services are singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular services are:

- Lazily instantiated – Angular only instantiates a service when an application component depends
  on it.
- Singletons – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance
  generated by the service factory.

[Github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/docs/content/guide/services.ngdoc) official doc.

Comment: Do you know if factories also "singletones"?

Comment: factories are also services:-)

Answer (score 0):

"All AngularJS services are singletons. This means that there is only one instance of a given service per injector."

Read:

[John Papa style guide.](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#services) (In addition to answering your questions, are great recommendations to work with AngularJS).

[AngularJS docs.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)