# Why are Factories more flexible than Services in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

According to [this source](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/top-10-mistakes-angularjs-developers-make),

> Why do the two styles exist if they can accomplish the same thing?
>   Factories offer slightly more flexibility than services because they
>   can return functions which can then be new'd. This follows the factory
>   pattern from object oriented programming. A factory can be an object
>   for creating other objects.

I'm having trouble connecting this piece of information to the concept of constructors in Javascript and object / prototype. Can someone help me connect the dot? Thanks.

Comment: in nutshell, difference between servise and factory in angular is just: service function call like `new service(dependency)`, and factory call like `factory(dependency)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [confused about service vs factory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory)

Answer (score 0):

**Service VS Factory**

A service is a constructor function that can be called with 'new' where as a factory returns an object that you may run some code before that is why it is more flexible.

To see a detailed example please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory) question. matys84pl talks about it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

***Factory***

These are practically singletons. So for instance you can hold data across calls to it.

```
factory('myFactory', function () {
   var internalList = [];

   return {
       add: function (value) { internalList.push(value); },
       get: function () { return internalList; }
   }
});
```

As you could imagine, if **`controller1`** pushed `Hi` into the list and **`controller2`** called `get()` immediately after, it would recieve `[ 'Hi' ]`.

***Service***

From the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#service-recipe)

> JavaScript developers often use custom types to write object-oriented code.

```
service('UnicornLauncher', function (apiToken) {

  this.launchedCount = 0;
  this.launch = function() {
    // Make a request to the remote API and include the apiToken
    ...
    this.launchedCount++;
  }
});
```

***Provider***

For some bonus reading, I'll tell you about a provider. A provider wraps a **factory**. Why? Because there are two phases in an angular application, the **configure** phase and the **run** phase. **Services, factories and values** ***AREN'T*** available during the **run** phase.

So, say we need to configure a service before it is injected into the controllers. We need to use a **provider**.

The [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe) have a nice example:

```
provider('unicornLauncher', function UnicornLauncherProvider() {
  var useTinfoilShielding = false;

  this.useTinfoilShielding = function(value) {
    useTinfoilShielding = !!value;
  };

  this.$get = ["apiToken", function unicornLauncherFactory(apiToken) {

    // let's assume that the UnicornLauncher constructor was also changed to
    // accept and use the useTinfoilShielding argument
    return new UnicornLauncher(apiToken, useTinfoilShielding);
  }];
});
```

so `this.$get` is basically the second argument of the `factory('...', ...`.

So if we use this in the configure phase we do this:

```
config(["unicornLauncherProvider", function(unicornLauncherProvider) {
  unicornLauncherProvider.useTinfoilShielding(true);
}]);
```

Notice how we ask for `unicornLauncherProvider`, we add that `Provider` suffix. Yet when we named our provider we didn't supply it. That is because angular automatically adds the suffix for you. If you want to access the **service** this **provider** creates, ask for the `unicornLauncher`.

Answer (score 0):

I had an 'Eureka effect' when i realized that `service` & `factory` are only syntactic sugar for `provider` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#provider)

The only difference between these two is the way Angular processes the passed value before providing it with the injector. 
When I get the object from the injector, I usually can't tell if it has been created using a service or a factory (or any of the other $provide methods)

So the Question is "How do I want to implement this?" and not "How do I want to use this?".