# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $q. Confused about DI syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-provider

Snippet 1 does not work. I get Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $q

```
/* Snippet 1*/
var mApp = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
mApp.provider('authProvider', ['$q', function($q) {
    this.$get = function(){

        authProvider = {};
        authProvider.Title = function(){

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve("promise resolved");
            return deferred.promise;

        }
        return authProvider;
    }
}]);
```

However, Snippet 2 works. I am confused why that is ? All the factory sample codes i have read, inject the dependency in the first line such as
.factory('MyFactory',[$q,function($q) {}]); 
Why doesnt that style work in the provider code above ? Also, why are we injecting $q below in the GET declaration but not further down in the TITLE declaration.

```
/* Snippet 2*/
mApp.provider('authProvider', function() {
    this.$get = function($q){

        authProvider = {};
        authProvider.Title = function(){

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve("promise resolved");
            return deferred.promise;

        }
        return authProvider;
    }
});
```

Please help!!!

(The code doesn't do anything right now. I am just trying to learn syntax)

Comment: That's because for a provider, the values are injected in the $get function.

Answer (score 3):

you can't do direct DI in `provider` , when you are using `provider` you have to inject your component in `$get` .

Reason you cannot  inject dependency into the `provider` directly is that the  `provider` runs during the module loading phase whereas the `$get` is run when instantiating the service you are providing.

You can not use any service during the loading/configuration phase of your modules.

Answer (score 2):

> All the factory sample codes i have read, inject the dependency in the first line such as `.factory('MyFactory',[$q,function($q) {}]);` Why doesn't that style work in the provider code above ?

This graphic has always helped me understand the difference between a `provider` and a `factory`:

[image: xxxxxx]
<sub>source: [simplygoodcode.com](http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2015/11/the-difference-between-service-provider-and-factory-in-angularjs/)</sub>

The `factory` function is the `$get` function of the `provider`. **Before** injection, the `provider` constuction function can configure the `$get` function. The `$get` function is where injection happens.

The `provider` construction function isn't injectable. That's why you get that error. The `$get` function is injectable and that is the function that you specify with `factory`. `factory` is just syntactic sugar for creating a `provider` with an empty constructor function.

### See Also

- [Confused about Service vs Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory) — [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34202620/5535245)