# Angular error when injecting service into my directive

Tags: angularjs

I created a simple service and a simple directive that use that service. Here is how it looks like:

```
angular.module("app",[]);
angular.module("app").factory('dummyService',dummyService);
angular.module("app").directive('dummyDirective', ['dummyService',dummyDirective]);

function dummyService(){
    this.name = "hello";
}

function dummyDirective(dummyService) {
    return {
        link:function(scope){
            console.log(dummyService.name);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run the code I get:

```
[$injector:undef] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/undef?p0=dummyService
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I will recommend you to read on how to declare a directive and factory before fixing this one

Comment: Sajeetharan I rad plenty and it seems to be OK, you have any helpful advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use service instead of factory.  In your code change

```
angular.module("app").factory('dummyService',dummyService);
```

to

```
angular.module("app").service('dummyService',dummyService);
```

if you want to use factory, you need to return object in the factory function:

```
function dummyService(){
   return {
     name : "hello";
   }  
}
```

[Demo on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/20051/)

See also: [confused about service vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory)

Comment: Damn I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You don't pass the dependency for the directive:

```
angular.module("app").directive('dummyDirective', ['dummyService', dummyDirective(dummyService)]);
```

Comment: You don't pass arguments to a function on that line because we don't execute the function there only passing it as a parameter(Angular suppose to pass the argument when it execute the function). Any way I tried your way just to be safe but it didn't help. Any more ideas?
Thanks!