# Services vs Factory in agularJs

Tags: angularjs

Is there any thing exist which I could do in service but not in factory or vice-versa? Basically I want to conclude the difference between the service and a factory.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

Comment: Please Google before posting a question, Have a look at top 3 results at Google ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory, http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at a the new post [.service() versus .factory(), the actual answer](https://toddmotto.com/factory-versus-service). by [@ToddMotto](https://twitter.com/intent/follow?screen_name=toddmotto)

> **So, what is a service?**
>
> A Service is just a function for the business layer of the application, it’s just a simple function. It acts as a constructor function and is invoked once at runtime with new, much like you would with plain JavaScript
>
> **Factory**
>
> Next, the confusing `.factory()` method. A factory is not just “another way” for doing services, anyone that tells you that is wrong. It *can* however, give you the same capabilities of a `.service()`, but is much more powerful and flexible.
>
> A factory is not just a “way” of returning something, a factory is in fact a design pattern. Factories create Objects, that’s it. Now ask yourself: what type of Object do I want? With `.factory()`, we can create various Objects, such as new Class instances (with `.prototype` or ES2015 Classes), return Object literals, return functions and closures, or even just return a simply String. You can create whatever you like, that’s the rule.

Enjoy