# Angular Js Contructor function for Service or factory

Tags: angularjs

I am looking for any constructor type of function in Angular. I have created a service but it is giving me an error. Please help to accomplish the task.

My error code:

```
var app = angular.module("app1", [])

.service('NumberService', function (a) {
    this.square = function () { return a * a; };
    this.cube = function () { return a * a * a; };
})

.controller('ServiceController', ['$scope', 'NumberService',
    function ($scope, NumberService) {
        $scope.getData = function () {
            //  alert('Button clicked' );
            var n = $scope.a;
            var ns = new NumberService(n);
            $scope.Square = ns.square();
            // alert($scope.Square);
            $scope.Cube = ns.cube();
        }
    }
]);
```

I want to create NumberService as Singleton class. In c++/java/c#:

```
class NumberService
{
    int a;
    public NumberService(int n){ a=n;}
    public int square(){ return a*a;}
    public in cube(){ return a*a*a;}
}
```

Comment: *" it is giving error"* ... why wouldn't you share what that error is? See [ask]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

when you create something with .service() it becomes a singleton. You really shouldnt do:

```
var ns = new NumberService(n);
```

cause it NumberService points to a singleton instance already. So just do:

```
NumberService.square(2)
```

Why do you want it to be a singleton though, you math operations are cleary utility methods, no need for a state?

Comment: It means it becomes static class as we access method name with class name not instance name

Comment: which is what it will become now with .service()  If you want it to become an instance I would suggest looking at .factory(). So do you want a singleton or instance? Happy to amend by answer with a .factory + instance solution if that is what you need?