# AngularJS and angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have asked similar question before, this time I am stuck with recording data to the blockchain using Angular js and Angular Factory. Please see the code below and advise me where I am wrong

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('application', [])
app.controller('appController',function($scope, appFactory) {
       $('success_create').hide()
       $scope.recordData = function(){
           appFactory.recordData($scope.data, function(data){
           $scope.recordData = data
           $("success_create").show()
})}}

app.factory('appFactory',function($http) {
var test = []
    factory.recordData = function(data, errorCallback) {
    test = data.field1+"-"+data.field2
    $http.get('/record_data'+data).then(function(output) {
      if (output) {
        callback(output)
    }).catch(function(error) {
          errorCallback(error) })}
return factory
```

Comment: There is syntax errors in your code, can you edit it ?

Comment: Sure i will do it now

Comment: What are `callback` and `errorCallback` doing? Can you post their code aswell?

Comment: + There are lots and lots of syntax errors in your code ..

Comment: Please check my answer I modified your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many errors in you're code, that I was considering not to awnser.

But as I felt the need to help you, take the code below as a guide.

```
var app = angular.module('application', [])

app.controller('appController', function($scope, appFactory) {
    // Use angular.element instead of the jQuery `$` selector
    angular.element('success_create').hide();

    $scope.recordData = function() 
    {
        // The factory returns a promise, 
        // so you can do the same just as you would with $http
        appFactory.recordData($scope.data).then(function(response) {
            $scope.recordData = response.data;

            angular.element("success_create").show()
        });
    }
});

app.factory('appFactory',function($http) {
    // You define the var as array, but you assign a string later on
    // So instead of var test = [] use var test = "" or just var test;
    var test = ""; // Or var test;

    var factory = {
        recordData: function (data, errorCallback)
        {
            test = data.field1 + "-" + data.field2;

            var promise = $http.get('/record_data' + data).then(function(output) {
                return output.data;
            });

            // $http returns a promise, return this to your controller
            // You can use the data it returns just like you 
            // would with the $http method
            return promise;
        }
    }

    // In your original code, you return the factory. But you never
    // Defined the factory.
    return factory;
});
```

Try out these simply tutorials to learn more about *controllers*, *services* ** and *promises*

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_services.asp
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

** *[Confused about Service vs Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory)*

Comment: Thanks for help I am testing this now

Answer (score 0):

@Tabz: modified your code.

```
app.controller(appController,function($scope, appFactory) {
       $("success_create").hide();
       $scope.recordData = function(){
           appFactory.recordData($scope.data, function(data){
           $scope.recordData = data
           $("success_create").show();
                    })
       }
})

app.factory("appFactory", function($http) {

      factory.recordData = function(data, errorCallback)

      $http.get('/record_data'+data).then(function(output) {
          if (output) 
            callback(output)
        }).catch(function(error) {
          errorCallback(error) 
     })};

return factory
```