# Using angular service to share data between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller, share

I am trying to have two different controllers communicate with each other.

**Controller 1**

```
function WelcomeCtl($scope, emailService) {
    $scope.save=function(){
        emailService.saveEmail(‘Hi’);
        }
}

WelcomeCtl.$inject = [$scope, emailService];
```

This controller is designed to take the text from a text field (with ng-model = ‘email’) and put the text into a service (emailService) so it can be used in the next ng-view (which is controlled by the next controller)
*//for testing purposes I am just putting ‘Hi’ directly into the saveEmail function*

**Controller 2**

```
function SignupCtl($scope, emailService) {                                           
    window.alert(emailService.getEmail())
}

SignupCtl.$inject = [$scope, emailService];
```

*For testing purposed I am using window.alert to display the value of getEmail()*

**emailService**

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
       .service('emailService', function (){
           var text =”start value”;
           return{
               saveEmail:function (data){
                  text  = data;

              },
              getEmail:function (){
                  return text;
              }
          };
      });
```

As a result of using Controller1 and Controller 2 as specified with this service, window.alert prints out “start value” instead of ‘Hi’

When I put more window.alert functions in the code to see what is happening I see that when save() is called, Controller 1 executes and saves a value into the service and express.js loads the next page.  Then Controller2 activates.  When Controller 2 activates it reinitializes the service, setting text back to “start value”.  Then when getEmail is called it return the value “start value”

This confuses me because I was under the impression that services were not initialized every time the were included in a controller.

**Consulted resources.**
[Better design for passing data to other ng-view's and persisting it across controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574765/better-design-for-passing-data-to-other-ng-views-in-angularjs-persisting-it-ac)

**I am also working off of the angular-express-seed**
https://github.com/btford/angular-express-seed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angular.js only works and keeps data on a single page.  If your page reloads (as you seem to indicate when you say "express.js loads the next page", then it reinitialized everything.

You should either:

- look at how to use Angular.js routing (http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) so that you stay on the same page.
- use something to persist your data, such as `localstorage`.  Find out more: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I thought i was just switching between two ng-views, so angular wouldn't have to reload, but i was in fact doing what you suspected and was switching pages.  Changed it so i just switched views and it all works perfectly.  THANKS!!!

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been looking for an alternative to Angular's routing!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXpHV5gWgyk#t=29

this guy explained it in a very simple way.