# What is the best practice for listing/editing items in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of employees in Employees view where I can add and a new employee and delete an existing one.

For listing the employees, I use an ng-repeat in the view and I can delete the particular employee by calling my splice method in controller with the passed Id and Index value.

and for editing, I use **angular(copy)** then update the edited value in DB. Everything is fine regarding to Add a new employee, edit and delete an employee.

I wrote all the codes in single view - single html and its too large in size. I used ng-show / ng-hide to perform add/edit actions.

I would like to break code to several views for add and edit the employee info and I use the same EmployeeController for all the CRUD operations in employee model.

If I break the employee.html to several views then I have to initialize the controller and ended up with losing the data. I can use **$rootScope** here to persist my data but it will pollute my structure as global is an evil thing.

Please suggest me a best practice to handle this situation. Thanks in advance!

Here is my code,

```
// To get all employee instances
$scope.getEmpList = function(){
    $scope.employees = EmployeeFactory.getEmpList();
}

// Update employee details
$scope.editEmp = function(empObj){
    $scope.updatedEmpObj = angular.copy(empObj);
    EmployeeFactory.updateEmployee($scope.updatedEmpObj);
}
```

Comment: localStorage, indexdb, server-side db. there are countless options.

Comment: Please suggest me any Fiddle examples or related stackoverflow solutions?

Comment: this isn't the place to ask such an open ended question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind words sir!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a service to hold your data and inject that service into each controller where you need the data. A service is a singleton, and is instantiated only once.

See [Using angular service to share data between controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100020/using-angular-service-to-share-data-between-controllers) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. It really helps.