# Passing data between controller via service won't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I'm trying all the approaches passing data between controllers using service, factory or broadcast. None of them works for me. I follow the exact solution online, but still unfortunate. I placed service inside my app.js.

App.JS

```
myApp.service('customService', [function () {
    this.list = [];

    this.setObject =  function (o) {
        this.list.push(o);
    },
    this.getObject =  function () {
        return this.list;
    }
}]);
```

**Controller #1**

```
myApp.controller('Controller1', function ($scope, customService) {
    customService.setObject({..});
    $window.open("/controller2", '_blank');
}
```

**Controller #2**

```
myApp.controller('Controller2', function ($scope, customService) {
 console.log(customService.getObject()); // Returns []
}
```

**Problem**

> It returns [] on controller 2 from controller 1, instead of object data.

Comment: with `getObject` you want to retrieve the array of objects or just one specific object?

Comment: previewService.getObject() doesn't throw an exception ? it's not the same name as customService

Comment: @Groben Should be same name.

Comment: @lealceldeiro just one object. But it doesn't return anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your service for storing a object under some specific key, and then retrieve it later given that key. You can define these keys whatever you like. I defined them in the same service so I can reuse them through all controllers. Something like this

**Service**

```
myApp.service('customService', [function () {
    this.keys = {"foo": "foo", "bar": "bar"};
    this.list = {};

    this.setObject =  function (obj, key) {
        this.list[ley] = obj;
    },
    this.getObject =  function (key) {
        return this.list[key];
    }
}]);
```

**Controller #1**

```
myApp.controller('Controller1', function ($scope, customService) {
    customService.setObject({"propX": "propX"}, customService.foo);
    //$window.open("/controller2", '_blank');
    /* I encourage you to use something like ngRoute here for navigating
     * so, you should do something like $location.path('/controller2');
     */
}
```

**Controller #2**

```
myApp.controller('Controller2', function ($scope, customService) {
 console.log(customService.getObject(customService.foo));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Second controllers returns "undefined", even though I had correct `this.list[key] = obj;`

Comment: How are you getting to `/controller2` route ? are you using _ngRoute_? I mean, how it's instantiated **Controller2**? the page should not be reloaded, neither you can open it in another tab. Please confirm this.

Comment: @Foonation, I didn't realised in **Controller1** I just copied and pasted the `$window.open("/controller2", '_blank');` part, but I encourage you to use a different approach here. See my answer edited, please

Comment: @Foonation, great!

Answer (score 0):

Are your controllers in the same page ?

> Angular.js only works and keeps data on a single page. If your page reloads 
>   (as you seem to indicate when you say "express.js loads the next
>   page", then it reinitialized everything.
>
> You should either:
>
> look at how to use Angular.js routing
>   (http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) so that you stay on the
>   same page. use something to persist your data, such as localstorage.
>   Find out more: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

ref : [Using angular service to share data between controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100020/using-angular-service-to-share-data-between-controllers?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

have you used routing? if u use then your code should be work.

Comment: I'm using RouteProvider when instead of state.

Comment: if you want to change page like $window.open("/controller2", '_blank'). that time your data can't pass on controller2. because that time your app is reload and services create new different instances.