# Modifying the parent $scope in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following situation:

- view+Ctrl 1: menu, select a city. $watch the city attribute, refresh the jobs in that city from the API when it changes, and modify $scope.model.myJobs accordingly.
- view+Ctrl 2: main view, iterate over the $scope.model.myJobs with ng repeat.

The response from the API comes smoothly and as expected, but it seems that angular has separate $scope.model.myJobs per each controller, even though controller 1 is within controller 2 in the HTML syntax.

Is there any way to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "angular" way to do this is to use a service that would provide you the model. Services are persistant even if you change the view and can be shared by multiple controllers. The concept is explained nicely in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574818/2187206

And for your information, you are facing this issue because a child controller only has a read-only access to the parent scope. When you try to edit the parent scope in the child, the property is cloned in the local scope of the child controller and the changes are not propagated. A quick and dirty way to correct this is to create a getter and a setter in your parent scope and change the model using this setter in the child controller. But you should definitively use a service.

Comment: Yeah, I felt that there is some kind of encapsulation here going on, thanks, although it is not quite the regular prototypical programming I'm use to

Comment: What do you mean by 'provide', How can a service control the attributes of a controller scope?, isn't it the other way around?.

I am indeed confused

Comment: Is there a way to change the URL to reflect the current selected option?

Comment: You can use $location.seach to add/read parameters in the URL without reloading the page. For  this to work, you will have to change the reloadOnSearch value of your route to false (unless you want the page to refresh)

Comment: Provide is probably not the right word. In fact,  in this example, the service IS the model. It holds the data and the business logic. The controller is only a link between the view and the model (as it should be).