# Ionic - Getting ID from previous page to update with new data on next page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I have some data from first page (or "Data Form" page) that needs to be loaded on next page (or "Add More Info" page) with same ID from first page before any controller is executed in my ionic application with sqlite database. In next page (or "Add More Info" page), I want add some new data to previous data with same ID before return again to first page.

You can check my flowchart below:
[image: flowchart]

How can I achieve that?

You can check out my repo [on github](https://github.com/rebelholic/Ionic-Sqlite) to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options of that :

**EASIEST BUT "dirty"**

You can use $rootScope to store all you data and initialise them on each of controller.

**Clean Solution parameters**
You can define ui-router parameters for each of the variables you want to send.
See ui-router doc : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

**using LocalStorage**
For persistance, you can use localStorage. It is clean and won't impact your routing ruleS.

**Better solution, using a service**
See that explanation concerning data persistance and services : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574818/3687474

I'll personnaly go for the service solution that is scalable, portable and testable

Comment: I prefer go for the service solution but How I can make "Add More Info" page loaded with same ID from previous page?

Comment: there is no JS on the github

Comment: its my js scripts: https://github.com/rebelholic/Ionic-Sqlite/tree/master/www/js and don't forget to read readme.md again.

Comment: also I mean not /DataForm/:id but just /DataForm/

Comment: You need to add therefore a getter & setter at AppCtrl level.
$scope.setId = function() { } //
Those functions can be called at child level  as $scope is herited

Comment: Could you give your example code on codepen.io or plunkr?