# Angular JS - Sending data from a directive to a parent controller

Tags: angularjs

I have an app where I use the [ngCart](http://ngcart.snapjay.com/docs) directive in order to store the items added to a basket. The problem is that this directive just has the functionality of sending the information about the items added by the user, but I would need also to send some information that I would get from a form.

So in order to send it in a single object, I need first to extract the data stored in the directive to my main scope, and then merge it with the data I get from the form.

For that I need to modify the `ngCart.js` directive. I tried to make a service, as adviced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574765/better-design-for-passing-data-to-other-ng-views-and-persisting-it-across-contr), but I don't get to get it working. The code I added to the directive is this

```
.service('ngCartData', ['ngCart', function(ngCart){

    return {
        data:ngCart;
    };

 }])
```

, but I get an error saying `Module 'ngCart' is not available!`

I'm totally new to services and factories in angular, so I don't know exactly where to look to make it work. I made a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kD1RWgYohACowj7vRkCS?p=preview) with my code (I tried modifying the `ngCart.js` file with the code above, but the plunkr shows the directive without any modification). I just need to be able to send the data stored in the directive in the scope ngCart so that I can listen to it in the parent controller (see the checkout section in the plunkr).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea in mind, and I'm surprised it didn't work for you.

I have edited your app in the following way (in `script.js`)

```
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, ngCart, myCart) {
     $scope.names = [...];
     ...
     console.log(myCart.cart);
 })
    .factory('myCart',function(ngCart){
        return {
            cart: ngCart.$cart
        };
 })
```

and it logged `{shipping: 30, taxRate: null, tax: null, items: Array[2]}`, which I think is what you need (I added 2 items before it logged).

Notice that adding a the service is redundant; The data is accessible whenever and wherever you need. Just inject ngCart to your controller/service/etc. and the updated data will be available to you.

Therefore, the following code is equivalent:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, ngCart) {
       $scope.names = [...];
       ...
       console.log(ngCart.$cart);
    });
```

A possible reason for the getting the error you got might be that, while editing the `ngCart` module, you had some sort of error (like a typo), which led to `ngCart` being invisible to angular.

Comment: I tried your second option, but I don't seem to be able to access the data (see updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/EVduknBjgfMouQDKnv2X?p=preview) If it can get it working this way, I will mark it as correct as it doesn't modify the directive code.

Comment: Check checkoutdata.html, when I try to access {{ngCart.totalCost()}} it doesn't appear any data in the view

Comment: But that's a completely different problem. First solve the current one: can you send http requests with ngCart's data, in addition to your custom data?

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Yep, I can access the data like that. I mark it as correct as is the cleaner solution (without affecting the directive).

Answer (score 4):

did you load the js file like this :

```
 <script src="pathto/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="pathto/ngCart.js"></script> or ngCart.min.js
```

did you load the module in your declaration module like this ? :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngCart']);
```

Comment: yep, the problem just arise when I modify that bit in the directive

Comment: Just noticed the plunkr was not working properly, now you can see it working :)

Comment: The problem was not related with that, the files were loading correctly (see the plunkr) :)

Answer (score 3):

You actually have this backward. You can't inject a directive into a service. You must inject the service into the main controller and into the directive so that you can use it as a bridge between the two. Services are singletons so if you modify the properties of a service those modifications will be available anywhere else it is asked for.
Your service will look something like this:

```
.service('ngCartData', [function(){

return {
    data:[],
    addData: function(newData){
       this.data.push(newData);  
    },
    getData: function(){
       return this.data;
    }
};

}])
```

then in your controller and directive use the ngCartData api, which would look something like this:

```
 $scope.someData = ngCartData.getData();
 $scope.someFunction = function(dataToStore){
     ngCartData.addData(dataToStore);
 };
```