# changing the value in one component using a second component using `$mdDialog.show`

Tags: angularjs, dialog

in 1 controller I have a variable:
`$scope.text = 'text';`

I click the button (in 1 controller). I open the window:

```
function clickDialog() {
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: 'SecondController',
        templateUrl: 'path/second.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body)                 
    });
}
```

in controller `SecondController` I click the button and I want to change the variable  `$scope.text = 'another text';` that is in 1 controller

How to do it?

Comment: Are you still stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it what you're trying to do:
https://codepen.io/yonathanb/pen/XYPwQZ?editors=1010

Just use the:

```
  preserveScope: true,
  scope: $scope,
```

in your opener function

Comment: it works. but I do not know how to do it for 3 Controllers
How to edit  variable `$scope.text` is in the 3rd controller) after clicking the button (it is in 2 Controller). The button is in the `$mdDialog.show` window in 1 Controller

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. In your question it wasn't about a third controller. My answer is relative to your question. Why do you have a third controller? Also, If you want us to find out your issues, please at least accept the answer.

Comment: My question 2, is under your answer. I do not know how to pass variable values between controllers. In 1 controller I have a window:
`$mdDialog.show({
        controller: 'SecondController',
        templateUrl: 'path/second.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body)                 
    });`
which has a button in the 2nd `SecondController` controller. After clicking the button, I want to change the value of the variable in the 3rd controller. I do not know how to do this?

Comment: In order to pass value between controllers in angularjs you have 2 options. 1) set the value to a parent controller (like $rootscope). 2) set the value into a service/factory then insert that value into all the controllers (best practice).
refer to that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123215/data-binding-between-pages-in-angularjs?rq=1