# $watch doesn't seem to work when value is evaluated from a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a repeater that renders gridBlocks. Each of these blocks has a property for *"Vote Good"*, *"Vote Bad"* or *"No vote"*  (for our purpose). This property controls, among other things, the CSS class of the block.

The data structure for the user vote is accessed via `userService`, which exposes methods for updating the votes, doing the ajax calls etc.

**My problem is this:**

I'm setting the `voteClass` property in the scope of each specific block via a call to the `userService`. I would like to watch this property and update the UI accordingly when its model changes.

However this does not seem to work - the `voteClass` doesn't re-evaluate and `$watch` isn't called even though the value for `getVoteClass(scope.block.id)` does indeed change.

I've tried using `$apply`, but that didn't seem to change anything.

I would very much appreciate your input...

**Update1** :I think that even though the value for `getVoteClass(scope.block.id)` changes, the block scope property does not. Is there any way to force the block scope to re-evaluate its properties?

**Update 2 - Problem solved:**
With the help of CaioToOn and Gloopy on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/pass-variables-between-controllers/12009408?noredirect=1#comment22461215_12009408) I realized that the fault lies with the fact that the scope property was referencing a primitive string. To overcome this, you can either watch a function, or use a direct reference to an object property (and not a primitive string).

---

Controller:

```
    var gridController=['$scope', "userService", function($scope, userService) {

        $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
            $scope.blocks = data;
        });

        $scope.getLookVoteStatus = userService.getLookVoteStatus

    }];
```

Directive:

```
.directive('gridBlock', function() {
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

                scope.voteClass=getVoteClass(scope.block.id);
                scope.$watch('voteClass',function(newValue, oldValue) {                                                
                    element.addClass(newValue);
                });

             }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Regarding your Update1, using @CaioToOn's solution: `function checkForVoteClass() {
  scope.voteClass = getVoteClass(scope.block.id);
  return scope.voteClass
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `voteClass` is not changing after the first call, although the return for `getVoteClass` is, but it does not get called again.

To not change your example, the right way to go would be:

```js
function checkForVoteClass() {
  return getVoteClass(scope.block.id);
}

scope.$watch(checkForVoteClass,function(newValue, oldValue) {                                                
  element.addClass(newValue);
})
```

But have in mind that everytime an $apply occur anywhere in the system, this is going to get reevaluated.

So, when getVoteClass would return a different value? On user interaction? If it is, then the best way to go should be something like this:

```html
<span ng-click="vote='bad'">Bad</span>
<span ng-click="vote='good'">Good</span>
<span id="thisIsYourElement" 
  ng-class="{bad: 'badCssClass', good: 'goodCssClass', 'undefined': 'noVoteClass'}[vote]"
  >Your content</span>
```

Of course, its pretty simplified.