# How to get global scope of page when route changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have **template (that is not defined by router)**, where I have 2 **links** (anchors), which changes variable

```
<a ng-href="#/service/service1"
   ng-click="activeService='minecraft'">
```

And then I have 2 images - their **class depends on the variable set by ng-click**

```
ng-class="activeService != 'none' ? { true: 'service-maximize-animate', false: 'service-minimize-animate'}[activeService=='service1'] : ''"
```

This works perfectly. But when I press **back button in browser** or change URL address directly, route changes, `ng-view` updates, **BUT the images** (in global template that is not set by router) **don't update** (they are not in `ng-view` (the template))

And here I face the problem - I have to use `controller`, but I can't use `controller` by router, because it's scope is only for the template (`ng-view`).

I also tried to use `ng-controller`, but it is not called, when route changes.

Is there any way, to solve it?
Also, I would like to know if there is any way to make the `ng-view` better readable, now it's horrible :)

Thanks,
Michal Hojgr

EDIT: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5rzGU/9/

Comment: Does it also have to work if a user hits the back button in the browser instead of in your app?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am talking about - and it's the only issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using Angular's Observer system. In controller, that was called after route has changed, it broadcasted an event

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('event');
```

and in controller, that had different $scope than the router one, it listens for `event`

```
 $scope.$on('event', function() {
       //code
 });
```

Hope it helps anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

A jsfiddle/plunker would be very helpful here.

From what I understand, the two controllers are independent. When you go back or forward in the url only `ng-view` changes because only `ng-view` deals with the router. The `other controller` doesn't know what is going on with `ng-view's controller`. Either you need to send a message from the `ng-view controller` to the `other controller`, as discussed here: [AngularJS: How can I pass variables between controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers-in-angularjs)

Or you could consider converting the second controller into a directive.

As for improving the readability of ng-view. Consider splitting it into smaller modules – directives where possible.

Comment: You jsfiddle doesn't work. There is no `ng-view` or `ng-app="myApp"`. It seems like you are trying to add a navigation bar to your view. Why not do that within the `ng-view` itself? If you need access to the `serviceId` you can get that through `$routeParams`:  [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeParams). And then based on the value of `$routeParams` you can set the `activeService` class.

Comment: The JS fiddle works - it changes and prints the variable when you click links. What doesn't work is the back button - and I want to solve it somehow :) I will try to do something with ng-view :)

Comment: Yes the `variable` works because angular treats everything in the HTML part as an angular app. The `myApp` module that you created doesn't actually run.

Comment: Oh, that's truth. However, I started writing the javascript and then I realised, that I don't know how to do it anyway :(