# Passing control to another controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am pretty new to angularjs and still getting used to the concepts.

This is the premise of my problem- I have 2 peer controllers (no parent child relationship), controller1 does say steps 1 to 10, controller 2 does something else until it finds something which is the step 7 of controller 1. So after that controller 2 needs to do the same last steps. Is there a way I can call a function in controller 1 from controller 2 so that there is no code replication. Do I need to create a service for this or is there a way to just call a function in another controller from one in angularjs

I have seen these 2 links and am wondering if there is an easier way to just call a function in another controller from one , may be using $rootscope.

[Passing data from one controller to other Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148950/passing-data-from-one-controller-to-other-angular)

[AngularJS: How can I pass variables between controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 2):

As the author of angular said himself in Angular Best Practices [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY), 
if your trying to figure out how to call one controller for another controller, **you probably should be using a service**.