# AngularJS - append data to json array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am stuck in one scenario where i have to pass data from one controller to another controller.

My app works like this:

View 1 -> gets some users from json array and displays in a table.

When i click add user in View 1, i get redirected to view 2.

View 2 -> has 2 input fields and a button (to add a new user).

When i redirect to view 1, i want the new user to get appended but this is not working.

To make it easy, i have demoed this here - http://plnkr.co/edit/yz6mpplZGh4q5bPDO2bc?p=preview

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can do this with a Service, [here][1] is an example :) 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12009408/3576459

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always overwriting the 'users' content on entry of the list controller.

Change your controller to

```
    ...
controller('UserController', function($scope,UserService){

if (!$scope.users)
{
  UserService.getUsers().then(function(data){
    $scope.users = data;
  })            
}
    ...
```

And bring back your 'correct'

```
 $scope.users.push($scope.user)
```

in your addUserController.

Answer (score 1):

`View2` directive needs to define that it requires `View1`. This will tell Angular to pass the controller for `View1` as an argument to `View2`'s controller.

You can then call a method `addUser(..)` on that controller.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate

Comment: Thanks for your point. This was new to me, i am exploring more on that the url you mentioned.