# How can I pass a variable to an AngularJs controller without creating a named property for it?

Tags: angularjs

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers-in-angularjs) but I am after something different - I don't want to have to create named properties on a service for the data I want to pass to a controller.

I have a service that provides an array of items, and each item in the array, is itself an array.

I pass the main array to a root controller (or directive) using a service, that's fine. After that I want to iterate each item in the array and create a directive with a controller for each item - how do I pass the item into this nested controller? It needs to be dynamic, obviously, because I don't know the number of items in the array.

If I wrap the nested controller in a directive, can I do it via the directive's scope?

Edit:

I need to iterate my items and pass each one into a nested directive or controller. So can I do something like this (in pseudo code)?

```
<mydirective>
  <ng-repeat item in arrayOfItems>
    <mynesteditemdirective>
      <mycontroller>
```

Comment: without a more concrete example we got nothing to go on. got any code?

Comment: No because I'm stuck at the design stage :)

Comment: i'm not sure if i'm getting the idea. what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I haven't been very clear. I've added a sort of example of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: You don't need to specify the controller inside the html tag, but in the directive definition. Take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Mario - I understand this, I was trying to illustrate what I'm attempting to achieve, rather than writing actually markup..

Comment: Actually, it's not what you're trying to achieve, it's your attempted solution of what you're trying to achieve :)

Comment: It would be in the parent scope somewhere