# $scope not behaving correctly when I try to get a variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a service, **ThingsService**, which speaks to my API. I also have a SharedData Service, following [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12009408/1296980). As far I can tell and test, SharedData is not the issue.

The controller, **ThingsController** uses this service to bring data into the application, like this:

```
$scope.getThing = function(id){
  ThingsService.GetThing(id,
    function(response){
      $scope.thing = response;
    },
    function(){
      alert("Error");
    });
};

$scope.getThing(SharedData.getNextThingId());
console.log($scope.thing); // => undefined
console.log($scope); // => thing, among others
```

Now, when I try to access `$scope.thing` it returns undefined.
The funny thing is that if I do something like `console.log($scope)`, there is an object called thing, and moreover all proper data is set within this object.

Does anyone has a clue what is going on? I'm quite certain I missed something.

**UPDATE**: Following Mathew's asnwer, this snippet

```
$scope.getThing = function(id){
  ThingsService.GetThing(id,
    function(response){
      $scope.thing = response;
      $scope.doStuffwhenThingIsReady(); //<- Here $scope.thing is set :)
    },
    function(){
      alert("Error");
    });
};
```

saves the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely because `ThingsService.getThing` is happenning outside of angular (via a post or what have you) so console logging directly afterwards isn't showing it. If you console log the `$scope` though it's a reference and so when you open it up you'll see it as the `ThingsService.getThing` is probably complete by then. You'll have to wait until `ThingsService.getThing` is done until you can use `$scope.thing`.